# How to return only the Date from a SQL Server DateTime datatype

Tags: sql, date, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT GETDATE()
```

Returns: `2008-09-22 15:24:13.790`

I want that date part without the time part: `2008-09-22 00:00:00.000`

How can I get that?

Comment: One thing to note is that SQL Server 2008 includes a separate DATE datatype for storing just dates without the time component.  More info here:  http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dev/datetime_2008_p1.aspx

Comment: Don't miss [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775/whats-the-best-way-to-remove-the-time-portion-of-a-datetime-value-sql-server/3696991#3696991) showing performance testing results of the various time-removal methods.

Comment: @Martin weird, thanks, [let's try again](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-trim-time-from-datetime).

Comment: Don't be mislead by the votes and accepted answer, Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/126984/1155650

Comment: @Rohit not everyone has SQL Server 2008 or later.

Comment: @hktegner - it must be misleading for those who have. Also there is one version below 2008 (ie:2005) where as after it we have 4 and counting.

Comment: @Rohit You are incorrectly assuming that 2008 is the only version people care about. (There are more versions in the wild.) The votes speak for themselves.

Comment: For future readers: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/ is also useful for getting the correct format when using convert.

Comment: SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @your_date))

Answer (score 2848, accepted):

*NOTE: This answer returns the original `DATETIME` or `DATETIME2` type. For an expression that returns a true `DATE` type (SQL Server 2008 and later), see [BenR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/126984/1501497) below.*

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @your_date))
```

for example

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

gives me

```
2008-09-22 00:00:00.000
```

Pros:

- No varchar<->datetime conversions required
- No need to think about locale

Comment: Is this way better or worse performance wise than using the convert methods other have suggested? Or is it negligible?

Comment: My method works faster. It doesn't require conversions to varchar and allows efficient date calculations

Comment: +1 Looks like this one is 35% faster than the double convert() method commonly used (which I also have used for years).  Nice one.

Comment: If this is 35% than the CONVERT method, you've got to wonder how much faster a built-in truncate would be - this has to be the most common datetime-related operation I ever do - I'm going to see about switching to this mechanism.

Comment: The only downside I can see to your solution is that unless you know what it is doing it is a bit obtuse. Using the double convert method makes your intentions more obvious to futire code maintainers.  BTW I have not downvoted you. I think I'll start using your method too.  Thankyou @aku

Comment: +1 You may be interested to see Ricardo C's edited answer (since it is community wiki and factually incorrect, I corrected it). You also got a prop to your question.

Comment: Also don't miss [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775/whats-the-best-way-to-remove-the-time-portion-of-a-datetime-value-sql-server/3696991#3696991) showing performance testing results.

Comment: @pilavdzice Setting a datetime to midnight of that day **does** LEAVE OFF THE TIME. What result are you expecting? The `datetime` data type cannot have *no time at all*. I think you are confusing data storage with user presentation. If all you want is a way to show a user a string that has no time portion (not zeroes, just blanks) then you simply want `Convert(varchar(30), @Date, 101)` or something similar. See [SQL Server Books Online • Cast and Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Worth noting that this does not extend to aggregating monthly, or yearly data.  You have to alter the terms in order for that to work. SELECT DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @YourDate),0) is extensible for mm/yy iirc

Comment: @aku Is there a way to get only Datepart as **"2008-09-22"** and not "2008-09-22 00:00:00.000" **without converting it into VARCHAR**.  Now I'm using `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @dateTime, 101) AS MyDate`

Comment: @user1671639 the datetime data type always contains both a date and a time, you can't sensibly store one without the other - unless you're using SQL Server 2008, in which case there are also separate 'date' and 'time' data types. If you use CONVERT() like that, you really want a string for later use, so you'll be stuck doing it like that - although it'd be better if you used date formatting functions instead of cutting the date off - or via `CAST(... AS DATE)` or `CONVERT(DATE, ...)`, which has been mentioned quite often on this very page.

Comment: I recommend changing the answer to `SELECT DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @your_date), 0)` because then `dd` can be swapped out for any other [`datepart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) keyword to truncate your `datetime` at an arbitrary level.

Comment: select cast(createddate as date) from table where createdate is your datetime column

Comment: The best part of this method is that you can fine-tune its granularity. You can strip seconds, minutes, "floor" the date to week, month, you can even modify it (by manipulating the `DATEDIFF` output) to round to nearest 5th minute, to nearest noon...

Answer (score 951):

SQLServer 2008 now has a 'date' data type which contains only a date with no time component. Anyone using SQLServer 2008 and beyond can do the following:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
```

Comment: There is also the 'time' data type in SQL2008 which answers the other half of the question of separating date and time.

Comment: FYI, I benchmarked different methods of trimming off time from dates and this was the fastest method. Granted the difference was small, but it was clearly faster over a large # of executions.

Comment: wt about sqlserver 2005??

Comment: @Dr.MAF Completing the circle, the pre-2008 answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype

Comment: In SQL 2019, what is preferred - this answer or CAST or CONVERT?

Answer (score 243):

If using SQL 2008 and above:

```
select cast(getdate() as date)
```

Comment: Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Type date is not a defined system type.

Comment: @FredrickGauss: What type, Date? What version of SQL Server do you use?

Comment: Beware! declare @date1 datetime = '2015-09-30 20:59:59.999'; select cast(@date1 as date) returns '2015-10-01'

Comment: @abatishchev sorry, that should have been `declare @date1 datetime = '2015-09-30 23:59:59.999';select cast(@date1 as date)`

Comment: @Nick: this is the issue with DateTime. use `DateTime2` instead and it works fine. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/2833

Comment: @Nick, to complement abatishchev response, your @date1 is indeed `2015-10-01`, due to `DateTime` limitations. Try without any cast to `Date`, it yields `2015-10-01`too! `declare @date1 datetime = '2015-09-30 23:59:59.999';select @date1` => `2015-10-01`

Comment: One of these easy to remember SQL tricks. As Mike says, only 2008 onward but, if you find a 2005 and previous DB somewhere, you may have a lot of issues :)

Comment: @NixVerAZ I believe there are exactly 0 reasons to run SQL Server 2005 in late 2016. This is pure idiocy, isn't it? A good sign of something terribly wrong there.

Comment: I like the use of the ANSI std "CAST()" - if portability is a concern (or even achievable) these days :).  Also preferred if wanting to preserve precision: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: @abatischchev - 1 reason that applies to more instances than you'd hold for possible: management refusing to approve the budget for updating antiques as long as someone manages to keep them running. Even SQL Server 2000 running on Windows 2000 is still alive. SQL Server 2005 Express: about 50 instances in my company alone (no, not mine, the one I work for).

Comment: The  '2015-09-30 20:59:59.999' issue doesn't seem to apply to Sql Server 2016 anymore.

Comment: One can go even further with the ANSI standard by using `SELECT CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)` (`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is equivalent to `GETDATE()`).

Comment: I prefer this over the `CONVERT()` syntax as it's more standards compliant (though, of course, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`)

Answer (score 88):

DATEADD and DATEDIFF are better than CONVERTing to varchar. Both queries have the same execution plan, but execution plans are primarily about **data** access strategies and do not always reveal implicit costs involved in the CPU time taken to perform all the pieces. If both queries are run against a table with millions of rows, the CPU time using DateDiff can be close to 1/3rd of the Convert CPU time!

To see execution plans for queries:

```
set showplan_text on
GO
```

Both DATEADD and DATEDIFF will execute a CONVERT_IMPLICIT.

Although the CONVERT solution is simpler and easier to read for some, it *is* slower. There is no need to cast back to DateTime (this is implicitly done by the server). There is also no real need in the DateDiff method for DateAdd afterward as the integer result will also be implicitly converted back to DateTime.

---

**SELECT CONVERT(varchar, MyDate, 101) FROM DatesTable**

```
  |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1004]=CONVERT(varchar(30),[TEST].[dbo].[DatesTable].[MyDate],101)))
       |--Table Scan(OBJECT:([TEST].[dbo].[DatesTable]))
```

---

**SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, MyDate)) FROM DatesTable**

```
  |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1004]=dateadd(day,(0),CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetime,datediff(day,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000',CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetime,[TEST].[dbo].[DatesTable].[MyDate],0)),0))))
       |--Table Scan(OBJECT:([TEST].[dbo].[DatesTable]))
```

Using FLOOR() as @digi suggested has performance closer to DateDiff, but is not recommended as casting the DateTime data type to float and back does not always yield the original value.

Remember guys: Don't believe anyone. Look at the performance statistics, and test it yourself!

Be careful when you're testing your results. Selecting many rows to the client will hide the performance difference because it takes longer to send the rows over the network than it does to perform the calculations. So make sure that the work for all the rows is done by the server but there is no row set sent to the client.

There seems to be confusion for some people about when cache optimization affects queries. Running two queries in the same batch or in separate batches has no effect on caching. So you can either expire the cache manually or simply run the queries back and forth multiple times. Any optimization for query #2 would also affect any subsequent queries, so throw out execution #1 if you like.

Here is [full test script and performance results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775/whats-the-best-way-to-remove-the-time-portion-of-a-datetime-value-sql-server/3696991#3696991) that prove DateDiff is substantially faster than converting to varchar.

Comment: Ricardo C, nice investigation! What version of SQL server do you use? On MSSQL2000 method with datediff performs slightly faster for me.

Comment: Just to note, I performed test 1000.000 times. For real-world scenarios performance difference will not be noticeable, I guess

Comment: Aku, I used SQL Server 2005 Express for this test. I work on 2000 at work, and I will test it with a table with over 24 million rows and see what comes out of it.

Comment: Aku, same results. No difference in performance over ten million rows.

Comment: The claims about equal performance are not true. Of course the execution plans will be the same!!! Measuring performance on these MUST be done by comparing CPU usage, not examining execution plans.

Answer (score 63):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111)
```

The above statement converts your current format to `YYYY/MM/DD`, please refer to [this link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/) to choose your preferable format.

Comment: This returns '2008/09/22' for me

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),101)  is `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

Comment: if you're sorting based on the raw text value (outside of the DB) then the 'japanese' format is better

Answer (score 51):

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 101))
```

Answer (score 32):

Just do:

`SELECT CAST(date_variable AS date)`

or with  with PostgreSQL:

`SELECT date_variable::date`

This is called typecasting btw!

Answer (score 30):

**For return in date format**

> CAST(OrderDate AS date)

The above code will work in sql server 2010

It will return like   12/12/2013

**For SQL Server 2012 use the below code**

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), OrderDate , 111)
```

Comment: This returns me date with zero time, not just date

Comment: can i know which version if sql server you are using?

Comment: @MaheshML it returns both date and time in MS SQL 2012.

Comment: Works like a charm in SQL Azure

Comment: @MaheshML There is no such thing as SQL Server 2010.

Comment: I expect "SQL Server 2010" means SQL Server 2008 R2 (it was *released* in 2010)

Answer (score 26):

You can use the `CONVERT` function to return only the date. See the link(s) below:

[Date and Time Manipulation in SQL Server 2000](http://www.sqljunkies.ddj.com/Article/6676BEAE-1967-402D-9578-9A1C7FD826E5.scuk)

[CAST and CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

The syntax for using the convert function is:

```
CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )
```

Answer (score 24):

If you need the result as a `varchar`, you should go through

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) --2014-03-26
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111) --2014/03/26
```

which is already mentioned above.

If you need result in date and time format, you should use any of the queries below

1. ```
   SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111)) AS OnlyDate
   ```

   > 2014-03-26 00:00:00.000
2. ```
   SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 112)) AS OnlyDate
   ```

   > 2014-03-26 00:00:00.000
3. ```
   DECLARE  @OnlyDate DATETIME
   SET @OnlyDate = DATEDIFF(DD, 0, GETDATE())
   SELECT @OnlyDate AS OnlyDate
   ```

   > 2014-03-26 00:00:00.000

Answer (score 23):

### If you are using **SQL Server 2012 or above versions**,

Use [`Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213505.aspx) function.

There are already multiple answers and formatting types for SQL server. 
But most of the methods are somewhat ambiguous and it would be difficult for you to remember the numbers for format type or functions with respect to Specific Date Format. That's why in next versions of SQL server there is better option.

```
FORMAT ( value, format [, culture ] )
```

Culture option is very useful, as you can specify date as per your viewers.

You have to remember d (for small patterns) and D (for long patterns).

### 1."d" - Short date pattern.

```
2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> 6/15/2009 (en-US)
2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> 15/06/2009 (fr-FR)
2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> 2009/06/15 (ja-JP)
```

### 2."D" - Long date pattern.

```
2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> Monday, June 15, 2009 (en-US)
2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> 15 июня 2009 г. (ru-RU)
2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> Montag, 15. Juni 2009 (de-DE)
```

More examples in query.

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = '10/01/2011';
SELECT FORMAT ( @d, 'd', 'en-US' ) AS 'US English Result'
      ,FORMAT ( @d, 'd', 'en-gb' ) AS 'Great Britain English Result'
      ,FORMAT ( @d, 'd', 'de-de' ) AS 'German Result'
      ,FORMAT ( @d, 'd', 'zh-cn' ) AS 'Simplified Chinese (PRC) Result'; 

SELECT FORMAT ( @d, 'D', 'en-US' ) AS 'US English Result'
      ,FORMAT ( @d, 'D', 'en-gb' ) AS 'Great Britain English Result'
      ,FORMAT ( @d, 'D', 'de-de' ) AS 'German Result'
      ,FORMAT ( @d, 'D', 'zh-cn' ) AS 'Chinese (Simplified PRC) Result';

US English Result Great Britain English Result  German Result Simplified Chinese (PRC) Result
----------------  ----------------------------- ------------- -------------------------------------
10/1/2011         01/10/2011                    01.10.2011    2011/10/1

US English Result            Great Britain English Result  German Result                    Chinese (Simplified PRC) Result
---------------------------- ----------------------------- -----------------------------  ---------------------------------------
Saturday, October 01, 2011   01 October 2011               Samstag, 1. Oktober 2011        2011年10月1日
```

If you want more formats, you can go to:

1. [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: To skip the culture, the custom formats lets you set your own, e.g. `FORMAT (@d, 'yyyyy-MM-dd')` to get 2011-10-11.

Comment: Using FORMAT in any case in SQL Server is at least 20 times slower than even some of the craziest conversions that you can think of.  I'd stay away from it for everything.

Answer (score 18):

Using FLOOR() - just cut time part.

```
SELECT CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: This method is not the fastest, and also implicitly teaches people that casting dates to float is accurate, which it is not. Please see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775/whats-the-best-way-to-remove-the-time-portion-of-a-datetime-value-sql-server/3696991#3696991) for more detail.

Answer (score 18):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()),103) --21/09/2011

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()),101) --09/21/2011

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()),111) --2011/09/21

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()),107) --Sep 21, 2011
```

Answer (score 16):

```
SELECT DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, GETDATE()), 0)

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY,0, GETDATE()))

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101))
```

Edit: The first two methods are essentially the same, and out perform the convert to varchar method.

Comment: These methods are all great, but which single one do you suggest using?

Comment: Note that the "correct" version of the top two is `select dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)`, because the `dd`s can then be swapped out for any of [the `datepart` keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) to clip the date at any segment you choose. (Also note that `dd` is just an abbreviation for `day`.)

Comment: be aware, that with the new DATETIME2 this truncation doesn't work every time correctly:

`DECLARE @myDate DATETIME2 = '2020-12-31 23:59:59.998911';`
`SELECT @myDate AS orig_date, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @myDate)) AS truncated_date`  

It results as  
orig_date: **2020-12-31 23:59:59.9989110**  
truncated_date: **2021-01-01 00:00:00.000**

Answer (score 15):

IF you want to use CONVERT and get the same output as in the original question posed, that is, yyyy-mm-dd then use `CONVERT(varchar(10),[SourceDate as dateTime],121)` same code as the previous couple answers, but the code to convert to yyyy-mm-dd with dashes is 121.

If I can get on my soapbox for a second, ***this kind of formatting doesn't belong in the data tier***, and that's why it wasn't possible without silly high-overhead 'tricks' until SQL Server 2008 when actual datepart data types are introduced. Making such conversions in the data tier is a huge waste of overhead on your DBMS, but more importantly, the second you do something like this, you have basically created in-memory orphaned data that I assume you will then return to a program. You can't put it back in to another 3NF+ column or compare it to anything typed without reverting, so all you've done is introduced points of failure and removed relational reference.

You should ALWAYS go ahead and return your dateTime data type to the calling program and ***in the PRESENTATION tier, make whatever adjustments are necessary.*** As soon as you go converting things before returning them to the caller, you are removing all hope of referential integrity from the application. This would prevent an UPDATE or DELETE operation, again, unless you do some sort of manual reversion, which again is exposing your data to human/code/gremlin error when there is no need.

Comment: Except, say, if you want a **query** that retrieves all records matching a user-supplied _date_ as the date-part of a certain time field. Good luck doing that only in the presentation layer. (You don't need convert, you can can use date arithmetic, but you get the idea…)

Comment: @Andrew why does that matter? You say `WHERE col >= @Date AND col < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Date);` - there is absolutely no reason to strip time from the column.

Comment: @AaronBertrand That only works assuming the input `@Date` has a zero time part. In case that isn't true, you still need to know how to truncate times server-side. I agree with this answer that formatting should be left to the presentation layer, but I didn't agree with an implication that leaving that for the front end means you don't have to know a quick way to truncate.

Comment: @Andrew all you have to do is make the input parameter DATE. My point is still that you should never have to apply any such truncation to the *column*, even though that is most people's first instinct.

Comment: @AaronBertrand and _that_ assumes you have control over the datatype of the parameter. Fine in a stored procedure, not so possible in other situations. Why not cast to be sure the parameter is the type you want and need?

Comment: @Andrew again, that's fine. My point - ***AGAIN*** - is that you should never have to cast ***the column***. [Please read](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx).

Answer (score 15):

To obtain the result indicated, I use the following command.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))
```

I holpe it is useful.

Answer (score 13):

Date:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() as date)
```

Time:

```
SELECT CONVERT(time , GETDATE() , 114)
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() as time)
```

Answer (score 12):

If you are assigning the results to a column or variable, give it the DATE type, and the conversion is implicit.

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = GETDATE()   

SELECT @Date   --> 2017-05-03
```

Answer (score 11):

```
 Convert(nvarchar(10), getdate(), 101) --->  5/12/14

 Convert(nvarchar(12), getdate(), 101) --->  5/12/2014
```

Answer (score 11):

Syntax:

```
SELECT CONVERT (data_type(length)),Date, DateFormatCode)
```

Ex:

```
Select CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),1) as [MM/DD/YY]
Select CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),2) as [YY.MM.DD]
```

all dateformatcodes about Date:

```
DateFormatCode  Format
1       [MM/DD/YY]
2       [YY.MM.DD]
3       [DD/MM/YY]
4       [DD.MM.YY]
5       [DD-MM-YY]
6       [DD MMM YY]
7       [MMM DD,YY]
10      [MM-DD-YY]
11      [YY/MM/DD]
12      [YYMMDD]
23      [yyyy-mm-dd]
101     [MM/DD/YYYY]
102     [YYYY.MM.DD]
103     [DD/MM/YYYY]
104     [DD/MM/YYYY]
105     [DD/MM/YYYY]
106     [DD MMM YYYY]
107     [MMM DD,YYYY]
110     [MM-DD-YYYY]
111     [YYYY/MM/DD]
112     [YYYYMMDD]
```

Comment: +1 for the neat info (maybe not performance optimized but clear and useful). It would be even better if you could post a link to the reference for the conversion codes. Optimally, if possible, present a way to pick ones own, customizable format (e.g. how to get *dd-yy-mm*) as well as incorporating the time part in the format (e.g. how to get *yyyy-hh-ss*, however weird that would be).

Answer (score 9):

Simply you can do this way:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, getdate())
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @your_date))
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

Outputs as:

```
2008-09-22 00:00:00.000
```

Or simply do like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE()) 'Date Part Only'
```

Result:

```
Date Part Only
--------------
2013-07-14
```

Answer (score 9):

**In this case, date only, you we are gonna run this query:**

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 111);[image]

Answer (score 8):

I think this would work in your case:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Person.DateOfBirth,111) AS BirthDate
//here date is obtained as 1990/09/25
```

Answer (score 8):

```
DECLARE @yourdate DATETIME = '11/1/2014 12:25pm'    
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, @yourdate)
```

Comment: This suggestion has been covered by other answers (more than once).

Answer (score 8):

Okay, Though I'm bit late :), Here is the another solution.

```
SELECT CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) as DATETIME)
```

**Result**

```
2008-09-22 00:00:00.000
```

And if you are using SQL Server 2012 and higher then  you can use `FORMAT()` function like this -

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Comment: Your first example still has a time component. The point of the question was how to remove that.

Answer (score 8):

Starting from SQL SERVER 2012, you can do this:

`SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00.000')`

Answer (score 7):

Even using the ancient MSSQL Server 7.0, the code here (courtesy of this [link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/42872-working-with-date-values-in-sql-server/)) allowed me to get whatever date format I was looking for at the time:

```
PRINT '1) Date/time in format MON DD YYYY HH:MI AM (OR PM): ' + CONVERT(CHAR(19),GETDATE())  
PRINT '2) Date/time in format MM-DD-YY: ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8),GETDATE(),10)  
PRINT '3) Date/time in format MM-DD-YYYY: ' + CONVERT(CHAR(10),GETDATE(),110) 
PRINT '4) Date/time in format DD MON YYYY: ' + CONVERT(CHAR(11),GETDATE(),106)
PRINT '5) Date/time in format DD MON YY: ' + CONVERT(CHAR(9),GETDATE(),6) 
PRINT '6) Date/time in format DD MON YYYY HH:MM:SS:MMM(24H): ' + CONVERT(CHAR(24),GETDATE(),113)
```

It produced this output:

```
1) Date/time in format MON DD YYYY HH:MI AM (OR PM): Feb 27 2015  1:14PM
2) Date/time in format MM-DD-YY: 02-27-15
3) Date/time in format MM-DD-YYYY: 02-27-2015
4) Date/time in format DD MON YYYY: 27 Feb 2015
5) Date/time in format DD MON YY: 27 Feb 15
6) Date/time in format DD MON YYYY HH:MM:SS:MMM(24H): 27 Feb 2015 13:14:46:630
```

Answer (score 6):

why don't you use  DATE_FORMAT( your_datetiem_column,  '%d-%m-%Y' ) ?

EX: `select  DATE_FORMAT( some_datetime_column,  '%d-%m-%Y' ) from table_name`

you can change sequence of m,d and year by re-arranging `'%d-%m-%Y'` part

Answer (score 6):

I favor the following which wasn't mentioned:

```
DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(yyyy, @mydatetime), DATEPART(mm, @mydatetime), DATEPART(dd, @mydatetime))
```

It also doesn't care about local or do a double convert -- although each 'datepart' probably does math.  So it may be a little slower than the datediff method, but to me it is much more clear.  Especially when I want to group by just the year and month (set the day to 1).

Answer (score 6):

I know this is old, but I do not see where anyone stated it this way. From what I can tell, this is ANSI standard.

```
SELECT CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)
```

It would be good if Microsoft could also support the ANSI standard CURRENT_DATE variable.

Comment: `select {fn current_date()} as today` works for me.

Comment: @brianary - That's nice, but it is not ANSI SQL.

Comment: That's fair enough, and your answer is nicely portable, but I figured as long as we're working around T-SQL, this also works (and shows that implementing ANSI CURRENT_DATE would be trivial for MS).

Answer (score 5):

You can use following for date part and formatting the date:

DATENAME => Returns a character string that represents the specified datepart of the specified date

DATEADD => The `DATEPART()` function is used to return a single part of a date/time, such as year, month, day, hour, minute, etc.

DATEPART =>Returns an integer that represents the specified datepart of the specified date.

`CONVERT()` = > The `CONVERT()` function is a general function that converts an expression of one data type to another.
The 
`CONVERT()` function can be used to display date/time data in different formats.

Answer (score 5):

On SQL Server 2000

```
CAST(
(
    STR( YEAR( GETDATE() ) ) + '/' +
    STR( MONTH( GETDATE() ) ) + '/' +
    STR( DAY( GETDATE() ) )
)
AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Date(date&time field)** and **DATE_FORMAT(date&time,'%Y-%m-%d')** both returns **only date**  from date&time

Comment: The question states SQL Server. This seems like MySQL?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE CAST ([my_date_time_var] AS DATE)= '8/5/2015'
```

Answer (score 4):

Starting from SQL Server 2022 (16.x), another option is `DATETRUNC()` function using `day` as value of `datepart` parameter:

```
SELECT DATETRUNC(day, GETDATE());
```

Answer (score 3):

My common approach to get date without the time part..

```
 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),GETDATE(),103)

 SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select cast(createddate as date) as derivedate from table
```

createdate is your datetime column , this works for sqlserver

Answer (score 3):

If you want the date to show `2008-09-22 00:00:00.000`

then you can round it using

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, (ROUND(convert(float, getdate()-.5),0)))
```

This will show the date in the format in the question

Answer (score 2):

My Style

```
      select Convert(smalldatetime,Convert(int,Convert(float,getdate())))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use like below for different different type of output for date only

1. `SELECT CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 103))` -----dd/mm/yyyy
2. `SELECT CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 101))`------mm/dd/yyyy
3. `SELECT CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 102))`

Answer (score 1):

Wow, let me count the ways you can do this. (no pun intended)

In order to get the results you want in this format specifically:

2008-09-22

Here are a few options.

```
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS 'Date1'
SELECT Date2  = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AS 'Date3'
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 121) AS 'Date4'
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 126) AS 'Date5'
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 127) AS 'Date6'
```

So, I would suggest picking one you are comfortable with and using that method across the board in all your tables.

All these options return the date in the exact same format. Why does SQL Server have such redundancy?

I have no idea, but they do. Maybe somebody smarter than me can answer that question.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: The last 3 are full dateTime stamps  being truncated.  121 is not separated by a 'T' while the other two are.  127 is more precise when working with DATETIME2 formats, but with regular datetimes, they round to the same values; so, in a different context, these return 3 different datetime values. As for the second one, A = B can be used in slightly different ways than A AS B using other functions than this, but using these functions, they work the same.  As for Convert vs Cast, Cast is a native ANSI function while Convert is SQL specific.  Convert has more options but not always as performant.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(100), GETDATE(), 102); --2023.02.15
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(100), GETDATE(), 23);  --2023-02-15
```

you can fllow this url to find some other format

example:
[image]

https://www.cnblogs.com/wintuzi/p/16164124.html

hope i can help you

Answer (score 0):

```
where datediff(day, [TableColumnName], '2024-03-26') = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use the code below to get only the date part and avoid the time part in SQL:

```
SELECT SYSDATE TODAY FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Not only is it for Oracle, not MS SQL - it's not even correct. To get the date part only from Oracle, one would use `TRUNC(SYSDATE)`

Answer (score -1):

```
select convert(getdate() as date)

select CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(date, getdate()))
```

Comment: I think you have copied in 2 select statements but copied the second select inside the first select.

Comment: Just my 2 cents worth, but the first SELECT statement:
“select convert(getdate() as date)” does not work. 
The “date” and “getdate()” should have been inverted like in the code below.
“SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() )”
 
You could also use the “CAST()” function as well. Either one will return the same results. 
“SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)”

Answer (score -1):

As there has been many changes since this question had answers, I wanted to provide a new way to get the requested result. There are two ways to parse DATETIME data. First, to get the date as this question asks:

```
DATEVALUE([TableColumnName])
```

Second, to get the time from the value:

```
TIMEVALUE([TableColumnName])
```

**Example:**

Table: Customers

Column: CreationDate as DateTime

[Customers].[CreationDate]: 2/7/2020 09:50:00

```
DATEVALUE([Customers].[CreationDate]) '--> Output: 2/7/2020
TIMEVALUE([Customers].[CreationDate]) '--> Output: 09:50:00
```

I hope that this helps as I was searching for a while and found many answers as seen in this question and none of those worked. IE `CAST` and `CONVERT`.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way would be to use:
`SELECT DATE(GETDATE())`

Comment: DATE is not a function dude.

Comment: To clarify... DATE() is a function in mySQL, but this question is about SQL Server.  In mySQL you can use the DATE() function to extract the date from a date time element such that DATE("2021-06-15 09:34:21") returns "2021-06-15", but GETDATE() is not a mySQL function, so he is mix-matching SQL languages. The equivalent of this in mySQL would be DATE(NOW())... but mySQL makes this completely unnecessary since you can just call CURDATE() instead.

Comment: `DATE` is a function in [snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_date).