# How to Convert following date to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I entered data into a database, but the date is off, it is showing to the seconds.

How can i do a select statement to get this:

```
2010-02-18 07:45:00
```

To This:

```
2010-02-18
```

I am not the computer guy here....Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SELECT Convert(varchar(10), DateColumn, 120) FROM TABLE

Comment: For more functionality on the style (format of the date) Microsoft has a helpful page : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: @Bill - if it works perfectly you should mark this answer as the correct/accepted answer so @amit_g gets the credit for helping you.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype for tips on faster solutions performance wize.

Answer (score 1):

For any SQL Server version

```
select dateadd(d, datediff(d, 0, datecolumn), 0), ..
from ..
```

or for your 2008

```
select CAST(datecolumn as Date), ....
from ..
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DATE('2010-02-18 07:45:00');
```

or variable in there

Or just change the column type definition from `datetime` to `date`