# How to select date without time in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

When I select date in SQL it is returned as  `2011-02-25 21:17:33.933`. But I need only the Date part, that is `2011-02-25`. How can I do this?

Comment: I guess he wants a string, and therefore it is no duplicated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return the date part only from a SQL Server datetime datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)

Comment: @TylerH there is any way to get     2011-02-25 00:00:00.000 instead of current time ?

Comment: @Thrainder there certainly is and I'm here because I can't remember how :(

Answer (score 181, accepted):

I guess he wants a string.

```
select convert(varchar(10), '2011-02-25 21:17:33.933', 120)
```

120 here tells the convert function that we pass the input date in the [following format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles): `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss`.

Comment: What is 120 for?

Comment: @Павле refer this article [Date and Time styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles)

Comment: i used this select convert(varchar(10), APPROVED_DATE, 120) , i got error column APPROVED_DATE datetime , how i will convert it ? error The multi-part identifier "LAB_RESULTS.APPROVED_DATE" could not be bound.

Comment: This works fine as long as you are not going to put it into a group function and try and order by the date. Prad9's answer will work better for this

Answer (score 663):

For SQL Server 2008:

```
Convert(date, getdate())
```

Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql

Comment: I get "Type date is not a defined system type."

Comment: i have no idea why this is such an upvoted answer. this question is for SQL Server 2005, *NOT* 2008. 2005 doesn't have the `date` data-type therefore rendering this solution as invalid.

Comment: It's upvoted because people come looking for solutions to their problem, not the authors. So if 110 people found this worked for them I think it's fair that it has 110 upvotes.

Comment: I have same error when i use select convert (table.order_date , getdate()); sql server version 2017 , the error (Type date is not a defined system type) the column type datetime

Comment: This will only give you the current date. What about other dates stored in the db?

Comment: This works fine for me in SQL Server 2017

Comment: @zizzipupp just replace the text `getdate()` with the actual name of whatever column you want to convert

Answer (score 92):

Using `CAST(GETDATE() As Date)` worked for me

Comment: where i will add my column name ?  select cast(getdate() as date , order_date)?

Comment: @Abdullah `CAST(order_date AS DATE)`

Comment: Found the same in article
https://learnsql.com/cookbook/how-to-get-the-current-date-without-time-in-t-sql/

Answer (score 71):

The fastest is [`datediff`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql), e.g.

```
select dateadd(d, datediff(d,0, [datecolumn]), 0), other..
from tbl
```

But if you only need to use the value, then you can skip the dateadd, e.g.

```
select ...
WHERE somedate <= datediff(d, 0, getdate())
```

where the expression `datediff(d, 0, getdate())` is sufficient to return today's date without time portion.

Comment: Oldie but goodie, used this trick dozens of times in older 2000/2005 DBs.

Answer (score 30):

```
CAST(
        FLOOR( 
             CAST( GETDATE() AS FLOAT ) 
        )

AS DATETIME
)
```

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/122-Getting-Only-the-Date-Part-of-a-Date-Time-Stamp-in-SQL-Server.htm

Comment: The most elegant answer on this page.

Comment: This doesn't work when you replace GETDATE() with a value of type DATETIME2.

Answer (score 16):

For **2008 older version** :

`SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)`

Comment: applauses for this! The others solutions only rely on the varchar(10) part, which just truncates the value.

Answer (score 14):

you can use like this

```
SELECT Convert(varchar(10), GETDATE(),120)
```

Comment: where i will put my column name order date ?

Answer (score 11):

In case if you need the time to be zeros like `2018-01-17 00:00:00.000`:

`SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 121)`

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

I would use [DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function. It is quite easy and you don't need casting. As an example this query :

```
Select  DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), DAY(GETDATE())) as myNewDate
```

will return

> 2021-01-21

The good part you can also create you own date, for example you want first day of a month as a date, than you can just use like below:

```
Select  DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1) as myNewDate
```

The result will be:

> 2021-01-01

Answer (score 4):

Its too late but following worked for me well

```
declare @vCurrentDate date=getutcdate()

select @vCurrentDate
```

When data type is date, hours would be truncated

Answer (score 3):

You can try this one too.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE(), 120)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit late, but use the ODBC "curdate" function (angle brackes 'fn' is the ODBC function escape sequence).

```
SELECT {fn curdate()}
```

Output: `2013-02-01`

Comment: I am honestly curious on how you think your answer is better than the accepted answer. Or where you perhaps referring to the other answers?

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson: Hmm, because ODBC-Functions are canonical functions and therefore indexable, unlike the nondeterministic SQL-Server functions. But never mind, it's only a scaling issue when you move from your 3 entries in testing to the 1 *10E6 entries in production, you get no problems during development ;)

Comment: If you run this query `SELECT {fn curdate()} FROM (SELECT 1) AS T(X)` and have a look at the actual execution plan (xml version) you will see that what is actually executed is `CONVERT(varchar(10),getdate(),23)`. So the datatype of this ODBC function is `varchar(10)` which means that if you want to compare the result with a `datetime` you will get an implicit conversion from `varchar(10)` to `datetime` on a string `yyyy-mm-dd`. That implicit conversion will fail with `set dateformat dmy`.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson: Looks like a bug, they should be using SELECT CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 112) instead.

Comment: "canonical functions and therefore indexable, unlike the nondeterministic SQL-Server functions" -- er, what?

Answer (score 2):

Convert it back to datetime after converting to date in order to keep same datatime if needed

```
select Convert(datetime, Convert(date, getdate())  )
```

Answer (score 2):

select DATE(field) from table;

field value: 2020-12-15 12:19:00

select value: 2020-12-15

Comment: Is this an MSSQL Server function? I checked Microsoft Docs but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Use is simple:

```
convert(date, Btch_Time)
```

Example below:

Table:

```
Efft_d       Loan_I  Loan_Purp_Type_C   Orig_LTV    Curr_LTV    Schd_LTV    Un_drwn_Bal_a      Btch_Time            Strm_I  Btch_Ins_I
2014-05-31  200312500   HL03             NULL         1.0000    1.0000         1.0000      2014-06-17 11:10:57.330  1005    24851e0a-53983699-14b4-69109
```

```
Select * from helios.dbo.CBA_SRD_Loan where Loan_I in ('200312500') and convert(date, Btch_Time) = '2014-06-17'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return a date type as just a date use

```
CONVERT(date, SYSDATETIME())
```

or

```
SELECT CONVERT(date,SYSDATETIME())
```

or

```
DECLARE @DateOnly Datetime
SET @DateOnly=CONVERT(date,SYSDATETIME())
```

Answer (score 0):

In PLSQL you can use

```
to_char(SYSDATE,'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Comment: consider transfering this to a comment.

Comment: This question is about SQL Server... not Oracle

Answer (score 0):

First Convert the date to float (which displays the numeric), then `ROUND` the numeric to 0 decimal points, then convert that to datetime.

```
convert(datetime,round(convert(float,orderdate,101),0) ,101)
```

Comment: `round` needs a third parameter "1" to truncate instead of round, otherwise when time is past noon it will get rounded up to the next day.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT DATEADD(DD, 0, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a scalar function and use format () to set the datatype you want to see. It is must easy on the maintenance later.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33072100)

Answer (score 0):

Personal favorite:

```
select convert(datetime, convert(int, getdate()))
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the simple pattern :

**TO_DATE(GetDate(),'dd/mm/yyyy')**

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Comment: What DBMS is this answer targeting? It seems to combine the SQL Server T-SQL `GetDate()` with the Oracle PL/SQL `TO_DATE()`. If it did work, it appears to involve an unnecessary date/time to text to date conversion, which is unnecessarily inefficient.