# SUM for all Jobs

Tags: sql

I have a SQL statment that I am trying to pull the sum for all JobTypes, for example, if there are 5 Jobs with the name "Process" they should show up on only one line with the Sum for the GB and KB. How do I accomplish this? Thanks.

so i would show: – jpavlov 10 mins ago
DEC 1, 2012, Data Extrat, sum(60), sum(56) – jpavlov 8 mins ago
DEC 1, 2012, Process, sum(60), sum(56)

```
   SELECT 

Jobs.DateCompleted  AS 'DateCompleted',
JobTypes.Name AS 'JobName',
SUM(Metrics.GB) AS GB, 
SUM(Metrics.KB) AS KB
FROM Metrics 

INNER JOIN
Jobs ON Jobs.JobId = Metrics.JobId 
INNER JOIN

Projects ON Projects.ProjectId = Jobs.ProjectId 

INNER JOIN
JobTypes ON JobTypes.JobTypeId = Jobs.JobTypeId

WHERE Jobs.DateCompleted 
Between '12/01/2012' AND '12/03/2012' 

GROUP BY  
Jobs.DateCompleted, 
JobTypes.Name

2012-12-01 04:28:15.477 Data Extract    0.200   210903.738
2012-12-01 04:40:07.913 Data Extract    0.781   819388.602
2012-12-01 04:48:45.493 Data Extract    5.278   5538731.844
2012-12-01 04:54:55.483 Data Extract    6.927   7265870.682
2012-12-01 14:11:38.357 Export  13.189  13828648.369
2012-12-01 16:57:54.840 Process 2.054   2156185.331
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `CAST (Jobs.DateCompleted AS VARCHAR(MAX))` From the `SELECT` as well as `GROUP BY`.

Assumption: `JobTypes.Name` and `JobTypes.JobTypeId` has 1 to 1 mapping.

**EDIT**

```
SELECT 
JobTypes.Name AS 'JobName',
SUM(Metrics.GB) AS GB, 
SUM(Metrics.KB) AS KB
FROM Metrics 

INNER JOIN
Jobs ON Jobs.JobId = Metrics.JobId 
INNER JOIN

Projects ON Projects.ProjectId = Jobs.ProjectId 

INNER JOIN
JobTypes ON JobTypes.JobTypeId = Jobs.JobTypeId

WHERE Jobs.DateCompleted 
Between '12/01/2012' AND '12/03/2012' 

GROUP BY  
JobTypes.Name
```

For the result to get summed up by `Name` field, you will have to remove the `DateCompleted` from `Select` as well as `Group By`.

EDIT2:

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125609/how-to-select-date-without-time-in-sql) and modify your sql.

```
SELECT 
convert(varchar(10), Jobs.DateCompleted, 120) AS DateCompleted
JobTypes.Name AS 'JobName',
SUM(Metrics.GB) AS GB, 
.....
.....
GROUP BY  
convert(varchar(10), Jobs.DateCompleted, 120),
JobTypes.Name
```

Comment: I edited the query, removed the casts but still no luck. Also, JobType.JobId is removed, so It can just be sumed by date and Job Name

Comment: Do you want to get date in the result without the time part such that the result is datewise details of each job with GB and KB?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i am after

Comment: DEC 1, 2012, Process, sum(60), sum(56)

Comment: @jpavlov: It is better to modify the question, instead of adding comments. This will help other people to look at your question in one go. Please delete the below 3 comments and add it to the original question.