# get only date from sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, date

I need to get the date part only from SQL. SQL data type is date but when i tried to call it it returns this value `01-Mar-14 12:00:00 AM`. The only part I'm interested in is `01-Mar-14` I've a long search in stackoverflow and microsoft and google but in vain.
[First search didn't work with me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125609/how-to-select-date-without-time-in-sql)
[also this one didn't work out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133081/most-efficient-way-in-sql-server-to-get-date-from-datetime)
Here is my C# code to get these values.

```
private void SearchName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)     
{                
      db.con.Open();
      SqlDataReader reader;
      SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from Employee inner join DatePics on ID=Emp_ID where EmpName='" + SearNametxt.Text + "' ", db.con);                
      reader = command.ExecuteReader();
      while (reader.Read())
      {
           NameSeartxt.Text = (reader["EmpName"].ToString());                   
           PassSeartxt.Text = (reader["Passport"].ToString());               
           IDSeartxt.Text = (reader["IDIssue"].ToString());
           expiryseartxt.Text = (reader["IDExpiry"].ToString());                  
      }
      db.con.Close();
}
```

but also return only the whole format. Tried to use this one, but fail.
`select convert(varchar(10), '01-Mar-14 12:00:00', 120)`

**EDIT:** latest code:

```
db.con.Open();
SqlDataReader reader; 
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from Employee inner join 
     DatePics on ID=Emp_ID where EmpName='" + SearNametxt.Text + "' ", db.con);
reader = command.ExecuteReader(); 
while (reader.Read()) 
{
 DateTime Received; 
 DateTime.TryParse(reader["ReceivedDate"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,  
                                    DateTimeStyles.None, out Received); 
 recsearchtxt.Text = Received.ToString("d");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass first argument as String, so convert the `reader["ReceivedDate"]` into string using `reader["ReceivedDate"].ToString()`

Try This:

```
DateTime Received;
DateTime.TryParse(reader["ReceivedDate"].ToString(),
              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out Received);
```

Comment: @BillG: could you please Edit your question with latest code?

Comment: `db.con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader;
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from Employee inner join DatePics on ID=Emp_ID where EmpName='" + SearNametxt.Text + "' ", db.con);                
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    
                  DateTime Received;
                  DateTime.TryParse(reader["ReceivedDate"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out Received);
                  recsearchtxt.Text = Received.ToString("d"); `

Comment: @BillG: first argument should be string, check my modified answer

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi: Thanks for following my initial (incomplete) answer. This overload of TryParse is better than the two steps I blurted out originally.

Comment: @KarlKieninger: i think yours also fine if you could use `ToString()` on reader data, but yes as you said `InvariantCulture` overload is better than normal 2 parameter method atleast when dealing with Dates :)

Comment: @KarlKieninger: i see you are already using `ToString()`, okay but i think you didnt notify OP about it.

Answer (score 2):

To get the date, use `convert()` with a format specification:

```
select *, convert(varchar(10), datecol, 121) as datestr
from Employee inner join
     DatePics
     on ID = Emp_ID
where EmpName='" + SearNametxt.Text + "' ";
```

This will convert it to YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: still the same . This is the statement i've used  ` SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select *, convert (varchar(10), ReceivedDate,121) as datestr from Employee inner join DatePics on ID=Emp_ID where EmpName='" + SearNametxt.Text + "' ", db.con);  `

Comment: The problem then is at the application layer and Karl's answer probably works.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something like:

```
DateTime issueDate;
DateTime.TryParse(reader["IDIssue"].ToString(), out issueDate);
IDSeartxt.Text = issueDate.ToString("d");
```

Though you'll need to use the right formatting param.

Here is a [fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/2jWnZw).

Comment: error ` The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.TryParse(string, Out System.DateTieme)' has some invalid arguments. `

Comment: @Sudhakar Tillapudi: The only one is       `CultureInfoConverter`

Comment: @BillG: you need to import `System.Globalization` namespace  , import this -> `using System.Globalization;`

Comment: @Sudhakar Tillapudi:     `DateTime Received;
                    DateTime.TryParse(reader["ReceivedDate"], out Received,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    recsearchtxt.Text = Received.ToString("d");`
error ` no overload for method " Tryparse" take 3 arguments`

Comment: @BillG: Try This: `DateTime.TryParse(reader["IDIssue"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out issueDate)`

Comment: @Sudhakar Tillapudi: sorry to disappoint you, but another error ` has some invalid arguments`

Comment: @BillG: are you sure? i dont think the error is coming from `DateTime.TryParse ` statement but from somewhere else ?could you please edit your question with latest code with which your trying?

Comment: @Sudhakar Tillapudi: 
     `DateTime.TryParse(reader["ReceivedDate"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out Received);`
  Tried to commented this line and there was no error

Comment: `Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.TryParse(string, System.IFormatProvider, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles, out System.DateTime)' has some invalid arguments `

Comment: Might be you can just force the first param ToString() which should make it work with minimal changes. Try to share via dotnetfiddle for the first time, so we'll see.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
expiryseartxt.Text = (reader["IDExpiry"].ToShortDateString());
```

Or this :

```
expiryseartxt.Text = reader.GetDateTime().ToShortDateString();
```