# Conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a table with a column that stores the date and time. I need to write a query to get only the date from that column,

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, LoginTime, 101) AS datetime) FROM AuditTrail
```

But, when I run the query I am getting this error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

the data in the column is datetime ex: 2012-06-18 12:08:04.000
so i need to extract the date only and remove the time
note that the [Logintime] column is datatime format

Comment: Show us the format of date in varchar field you have?

Comment: in which Date format ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select date without time in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125609/how-to-select-date-without-time-in-sql)

Comment: this is the format of the date [2012-06-18 12:08:09.000]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL - The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838344/sql-the-conversion-of-a-varchar-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `ISDATE()` function in SQL Server. If 1, select valid date. If 0 selects invalid dates.

```
SELECT cast(CONVERT(varchar, LoginTime, 101) as datetime)  
FROM AuditTrail 
WHERE ISDATE(LoginTime) = 1
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b3cb/2) to view result

**EDIT :**

As per your update **i need to extract the date only and remove the time**, then you could simply use the inner `CONVERT`

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, LoginTime, 101) FROM AuditTrail
```

or

```
SELECT LEFT(LoginTime,10) FROM AuditTrail
```

**EDIT 2 :**

The major reason for the error will be in your date in WHERE clause.ie,

```
SELECT cast(CONVERT(varchar, LoginTime, 101) as datetime)  
FROM AuditTrail
where CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, LoginTime, 101) AS DATE) <= 
CAST('06/18/2012' AS DATE)
```

will be different from

```
SELECT cast(CONVERT(varchar, LoginTime, 101) as datetime)  
FROM AuditTrail
where CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, LoginTime, 101) AS DATE) <= 
CAST('18/06/2012' AS DATE)
```

**CONCLUSION**

In **EDIT 2** the first query tries to filter in `mm/dd/yyyy` format, while the second query tries to filter in `dd/mm/yyyy` format. Either of them will fail and throws error

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

So please make sure to filter date either with `mm/dd/yyyy` or with `dd/mm/yyyy` format, whichever works in your db.

Comment: the last query posted by @sarath is working fine but when i use where statement to compare between to dates its not wokring
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, LoginTime, 101) FROM AuditTrail 
where CONVERT(VARCHAR, LoginTime, 101) <= '06/18/2012'

Comment: Try with **where CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, LoginTime, 101) AS DATE) <= CAST('06/18/2012' AS DATE)** @Noora

Comment: i am getting [Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.]

Comment: Can u show me the query you are trying to do? @Noora

Comment: the same query writtin above

Comment: note that the sql server that i am trying to run the query is 2000 which is an old server

Comment: Then why did u add **SQL Server 2008** as tag in the question? You should have told it before @Noora

Comment: oh sorry my mistake i just checked with the admin and he confirm to me, i thought it was 2008, is it matter for 2000 or 2008?

Comment: I haven't used Sql 2000 yet. Not sure the above will work on 2000 @Noora

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70089/discussion-between-noora-and-sarath-avanavu).

Answer (score 1):

hope this may help you:

```
SELECT  CAST(LoginTime AS DATE)
         FROM    AuditTrail
```

If you want to have some filters over this datetime or it's different parts, you can use built-in functions such as Year and Month

Answer (score 1):

as you can see on the answer to this question:
[Conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86313/conversion-of-a-varchar-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in-an-out-of/183537#183537)

```
-- set the dateformat for the current session
set dateformat dmy

-- The conversion of a varchar data type 
-- to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
select cast('2017-08-13 16:31:31'  as datetime)

-- get the current session date_format
select date_format
from sys.dm_exec_sessions
where session_id = @@spid

-- set the dateformat for the current session
set dateformat ymd

-- this should work
select cast('2017-08-13 16:31:31'  as datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem. I have stored dates in SQL Server with format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS' for about 20 years, but today that was not able anymore from a C# solution using OleDbCommand and a UPDATE query.

The solution to my problem was to remove the hyphen - in the format, so the resulting formatting is now 'YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS'. I have no idea why my previous formatting not works anymore, but I suspect there is something to do with some Windows updates for ADO.

Answer (score -1):

> *some problem, but I find the solution, this is :*

---

> 2  February Feb   28 (29 in leap years)

**this is my code**

```
 public string GetCountArchiveByMonth(int iii)
        {
// iii: is number of months, use any number other than (**2**)

            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd10 = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd10.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd10.CommandText = "select count(id_post) from posts where dateadded between CONVERT(VARCHAR, @start, 103) and CONVERT(VARCHAR, @end, 103)";
            cmd10.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", "" + iii + "/01/2019");
            cmd10.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", "" + iii + "/30/2019");
            string result = cmd10.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            con.Close();

            return result;
        }
```

**now for test**

```
 lbl1.Text = GetCountArchiveByMonth(**7**).ToString();  // here use any number other than (**2**)
```

**

> because of check `**February**` is maxed **28** days,

**