# Use a manipulated date in an INSERT statement, in SQL Server Compact

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I'm using SQL Server Compact.

To get a date without the time, [I do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5125624/3959480):

```
CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME);
```

To insert a new record, where the date is the smallest from another table, I do this:

```
INSERT INTO [Product] ([OrderDate], [Name]) 
SELECT TOP(1) [OrderDate], 'Widget' FROM [OtherProduct];
```

*How do I combine those two ideas? I want something like this, but it doesn't work*:

```
INSERT INTO [Product] ([OrderDate], [Name]) 
SELECT CAST(FLOOR(CAST(TOP(1) [OrderDate] AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME), 'Widget' FROM [OtherProduct];
```

The error:

```
There was an error parsing the query. [ Token in error = TOP ]
```

Comment: `TOP(1)` should be `SELECT TOP(1) CAST(FLOOR(CAST( [OrderDate] AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have to specify `TOP(1)` on right place

```
INSERT INTO [Product] ([OrderDate], [Name]) 
SELECT TOP(1) CAST(FLOOR(CAST([OrderDate] AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME), 'Widget' FROM [OtherProduct];
```