# How to separate date and time from a datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a datetime record.
I need to select the record using date or time.

Let's say that I have this format `1/1/2001 13:33:00` in the database

My question is: If I enter the date, the time or both, I should obtain the rows that have either same date or the same time. **How can I achieve this**?

The convert function `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Travel.Travel_DateTime, 110)` 
returns the dates if their time is like the default `00:00:00`

Comment: please tell that how you are passing date or time value ..

Comment: What is the type of the column in the database?  VARCHAR?  If so, why did you decide not to use a built-in DATE/TIME type?  They're there to make life easier for users, including you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the date part only from a SQL Server datetime datatype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Note that I'm assuming MySQL)

Just use the [DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) and [TIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) functions:

```
SELECT blah FROM tbl WHERE DATE(some_datetime_field) = '2012-04-02';
```

That will select any rows such that the date part of some_datetime_field is 4 Apr 2012.

The same idea applies with TIME:

```
SELECT blah FROM tbl WHERE TIME(some_datetime_field) = '14:30:00';
```

So, to get all rows where the date is 5 Apr 2012 or the time is 2:30 PM, you just combine the two:

```
    SELECT blah FROM tbl WHERE DATE(some_datetime_field) = '2012-04-02' OR TIME(some_datetime_field) = '14:30:00';
```

**---Edit---**

For SQL server, you should be able to use:

```
CONVERT(DATE, some_datetime_field) = '2012-04-02'
```

(From [How to return the date part only from a SQL Server datetime datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype))

Comment: @RasheedKhalilSalem your question should specify that then.  I tend to assume questions that do not specify are MySQL :).

Comment: thanks a lot its working 
and i am sorry for not specified that i am using sql i thought that the tag in enough

Comment: CONVERT(time ,travel_datetime) for the time 
thank you very  much :)

Answer (score 2):

say you are passing date and time in `l_DATE` and `l_TIME` variable ..

then you can use following query..

```
select * from your_table 
where to_char(date_field,'DD/MM/YYYY') = l_DATE 
   or to_char(date_field ,'HH:MI:SS') = l_TIME
```

If you are using Oracle database as DBMS then you can use above query and it should give you your desired answer/ result...