# How to extract date from datetime stored as a varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I convert the string 'Fri,  9 Mar 2012 10:43:21 +0000 (UTC)', stored as a `varchar(max)`, to the `datetime` value '09-03-2012', which is the date part of the string?

Comment: What is the datatype in the DB?  Is it a `datetime`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the date part only from a SQL Server datetime datatype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)

Comment: No,the column is of varchar(max).

Answer (score 0):

According to MS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

> The CONVERT() function is a general function that converts an expression of one data type to another.
> The CONVERT() function can be used to display date/time data in different formats.

and the table lists 105 as the code for the style you want.

So, for your example date:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 'Fri, 9 Mar 2012 10:43:21 +0000 (UTC)', 105)
```

should probably do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use convert and reference to this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

e.g.
    CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112)

Answer (score 0):

I had to chop up your date first, but here goes:

```
DECLARE @ds varchar(30)='Fri, 9 Mar 2012 10:43:21 +0000 (UTC)';
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10)
,CAST(SUBSTRING(@ds
,CHARINDEX(' ',@ds)
,LEN(@ds)-(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',@ds)+6))
AS DATETIME)
,105    
)
```

Result:

```
09-03-2012
```

Comment: Why the down vote? Does this not work? If you have a better idea you are welcome to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL Server 2012, you can try this:

select CONVERT(date, TRY_PARSE('Fri, 9 Mar 2012 10:43:21 +0000' AS datetime2))

NOTE: (UTC) is removed, it didn't parse correctly.

Also, be aware if you need to localize that time value. For example, I live in AZ, so typically I just subtract -7 hrs from UTC times to localize. You will need to make similar adjustments based on the time zone