# SQL SELECT NOW()

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Hey ya'll sorry for all the caps in the title, but its actually suppose to be like that.

I am running this in query

`SELECT NOW()`

and it returns this

`2012-05-14 17:35:37`

how do I remove the time, I only want the date.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the date part only from a SQL Server datetime datatype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)

Comment: We shouldnt have to answer this question, its basic mysql and can be found in the manual. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about [CURDATE()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_curdate.asp)?

```
SELECT CURDATE()
```

(Note: this is listed as MySQL in the webpage. Unsure what vendor/version of SQL you're running.)

Answer (score 2):

This MySQL select should return the date without the time.

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE();
```

enjoy :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this might also work

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`LEFT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_left) function:

```
SELECT LEFT(NOW(), 10);
```

Here's a little demo:

```
mysql> SELECT LEFT(NOW(), 10);
+-----------------+
| LEFT(NOW(), 10) |
+-----------------+
| 2012-05-14      |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

This woked for me like perdfect:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(myDate) = DATE(NOW())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DATE(NOW())
```

is what I use - it just keeps the date portion

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a date format and use `NOW()`.

```
| date_int | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
mysql> UPDATE borderaux SET date_int = NOW();

+------------+
| date_int   |
+------------+
| 2013-07-15 |
+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

this might also work for mySQL:

```
Select CURDATE();
```