# Select all records 'younger' than 7 days

Tags: sql, select, date-range

I want to select all the records from `[Orders]` that have a `[Submissiondate]` less than 7 days.

I'm completely stumped. This is the query I'm executing:

```
SELECT * FROM [Orders] WHERE ([SubmissionDate] < @SubmissionDate)
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: Any advance? did you get the solution?

Answer (score 5):

If you mean you want rows with `SubmissionDate` between `@SubmissionDate` and `@SubmissionDate - 7 days`, then this is how I would implement that in Transact-SQL:

```
WHERE [SubmissionDate] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -7, @SubmissionDate)
                           AND @SubmissionDate
```

Note that `BETWEEN` implies `>=` and `<=`. If you need strict inequalities, make it something like this:

```
WHERE [SubmissionDate] > DATEADD(DAY, -7, @SubmissionDate)
  AND [SubmissionDate] < @SubmissionDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the sql parameter `@SubmissionDate` is the date (and time) now. You could use the following query that will return those `[Orders]` **submitted within the last 7 days**:

```
SELECT * FROM [Orders] WHERE ([SubmissionDate] >= DATEADD(DD, -7, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @SubmissionDate))))
```

Two important remarks to this solution:

1. Time 'part' is being removed from @SubmissionDate.
2. As there is no 'Date To' restriction, do **includes** the `[Orders]` submitted
   'today' (until the time the query is being executed).

The following code is just to get the date 'part' only of a date-time (extracted from this other [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)).

```
DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @SubmissionDate))
```

Comment: Good point about resetting the time part. But if you assume that `@SubmissionDate` represents the current date and time, then there's not very much point in using the argument, is there? You could just use `GETDATE()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead.

Comment: What I mean is, if the OP *is* using an argument, then it is likely (in my opinion) that the argument represents an *arbitrary* timestamp, not always the current one.

Comment: @AndriyM yes I see your point, maybe that's something the author can clarify, if it is intended that `@SubmissionDate` param. allocates the current date (and time). Well, I always try to avoid in the queries to  use directly date and time provided by the db-server and always use parameters, so I did feel comfortable with the assumption that `@SubmissionDate` was meant to allocate the current date and time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

> SELECT * FROM [Orders] WHERE [submission_date] < NOW() - INTERVAL 7
>   DAY;

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this [DATEDIFF](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp)

```
SELECT * FROM [Orders] WHERE  datediff(d,SubmissionDate,GETDATE()) > 7
```

where GetDate() is today's date and the `d` is difference in days

```
select datediff(d,'2012/06/23',GETDATE())
```

should give you 7 because it's 7 days ago