# How to count only once for a specified record?

Tags: c#, sql

How to count only once for a specified row even if the row exists more than once?

For instance I have a SQL query

```
SELECT COUNT(Date) 
FROM mytable 
WHERE name like '%John%'
```

But it counts all John's number. What I need is, if I find a name `John`, I want to count only one time, no matter John's name exists more than once.

To illustrate

```
Name       Date
John       06-09-2012 1am
Robert     06-09-2012 2am
John       06-09-2012 3am 
John       06-09-2012 4am
Robert     06-09-2012 5am
```

Results should be 1 for John.

Comment: the result will be the top one / the bottom one ?

Comment: you mean to ignore the time component ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/113055/570150

Comment: My intention is to count appearance of each John in terms of day, but i did not mention that. If you consider with that way, how to write sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `COUNT` `Distinct Date` and also need to use `GROUP BY` clause like this:

```
SELECT Name,COUNT(DISTINCT CONVERT(varchar,date,103)) AS NameCount
FROM mytable WHERE name LIKE '%John%'
GROUP BY name
```

[SEE THIS FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/961ac/4) for `name LIKE '%John%'`.

Also, for each user try this:

```
SELECT Name,COUNT(DISTINCT CONVERT(varchar,date,103)) AS NameCount
FROM mytable GROUP BY name
```

[SEE THIS FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/961ac/6) for Each user.

Comment: @JohnSmith See the answer again which is more improved.

Answer (score -1):

Update query as per clear requirements

For oracle

> SELECT count(distinct (extract day from date)) FROM mytable WHERE name
>   like '%John%' and Date is not null;

Comment: Thanks, What about count each name for each day. The results should be 1 for 06-09-2012 with name=john, and 1 for 07-09-2012 with name=john. So, for each day john should be counted. How can I do that ?

Comment: @JohnSmith [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877717/how-to-count-only-once-for-a-specified-record/11877846#11877846) again. This is exactly what you want.

Comment: Sorry I did not you question first time, answer by @hims056 will solve your problem