# How to remove timestamp from date without converting it in varchar in sql server?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am comparing a "date" with current date(GETDATE()) using DATEDIFF().

The problem i am facing is that the "date" is in dd/MM/yyyy format and the date i am getting 
using GETDATE() includes the timestamp also.

Please guide me how to remove the timestamp from GETDATE(),and also want to compare these two dates.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the date part only from a SQL Server datetime datatype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)

Comment: If the date is in a `datetime` column or variable, it doesn't *have* a format. It's just a `datetime`. If you force such a value to be converted to a string, it may appear in a particular format, but that *does* *not* mean that the "date" *has* a format.

Answer (score 4):

> Please guide me how to remove the timestamp from GETDATE(),

The [documentation for `GETDATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) has this contribution at the bottom of the page:

```
CAST(DATEDIFF(Day, 0, GETDATE()) AS DATETIME)
```