# Convert database column format in SqlCommand

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2005

In a `SELECT` command to my SQL Server 2005 database, I need to convert the `OrderDelDateTime` column (which is in `datetime` format) to a date format so that I can select all rows with today's date, regardless of the time.

Here is what I've got:

```
cmd = New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Orders] where [OrderDelDateTime] = '" + Now.Date + "'", conn)
```

Obviously this returns zero results because `11/30/2012 5:30:00 PM` (in db) doesn't equal `Now.Date` (`11/30/2012`).

I'm using VB.Net.

Comment: Since you're still on SQL Server 2005, converting the `DATETIME` in the database table to look at only the date portion is a bit involved - [see this other SO question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype) on how to do this. Once you've converted your `OrderDelDateTime` to only date, you can then compare it to `Now.Date`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your query like this:

```
select *
from Orders
where OrderDelDateTime between @Date1 and @Date2
```

Then from C#, pass the following two parameters:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date1", Now.Date);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date2", Now.Date.AddDays(1).AddMilliseconds(-1));
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92105/1

Comment: I like it - I should have come with that "out of the box" thinking.  Thanks.

Comment: This will also select records with the next day if the time is 00:00:00

Comment: Dim dteYesterday As DateTime = Now.Date.AddDays(-1) & " 11:59:59 PM"
Dim dteTomorrow As DateTime = Now.Date.AddDays(+1) & " 12:01:01 AM"                                                                 cmd = New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Orders] where [OrderDelDateTime] > '" + dteYesterday + "' and [OrderDelDateTime] < '" + dteTomorrow + "'", conn)

Comment: @user1375002: I thought you were doing it in C# instead of VB.NET. Btw, you don't need to append times for SQL Query. If you just add a day, SQL will always assume its 12AM if there is no time with a date.

Comment: @user1375002: "12:01:01 AM" should be "12:00:00 AM". But, like Muhammad mentioned, you do not really need to specify time. All you have to do is check whether payment is greater or equal then today without mentioning any time and less then tomorrow without mentioning any time. Muhammad's original answer is not accurate because it will also return any order with tomorrow's date if the time is 00:00:00

Comment: @George: I see your point. Good catch. I updated the code above to subtract 1 millisecond.

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd = New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT * FROM [Orders] where [OrderDelDateTime] >= {0} and  [OrderDelDateTime] < {1}", Now.Date, Now.Date.AddDays(1)), conn)
```