# fetch only date from date datatype in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to return the date part only from a SQL Server datetime datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)

I need to fetch only date from sql server eventhough i have used date datatype i am getting time also. but in database `n_strat_date` column has only date value not the time value.

My table:

[image]

My Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of how you store the dates in SQL, if you load this data in C# `DateTime` values, they will always have a time part (which is `12:00:00 AM`, unless otherwise specified).

Your problem here has nothing to do with SQL; it's a formatting issue in your application.

Concretely, if you had the DateTime value in a variable called `startDate`, instead of printing out to the form `startDate` or `startDate.ToString()`, use an explicit format, like this: `startDate.ToString("M/d/yyyy")`.

Here's an [online test](http://ideone.com/fRUYe6) to see how it works.

Comment: here i am filling dataset value to string strStartDate .so when i use as you suggestion its giving error. My code:                           string strStartDate = dsViewTrip.Tables[0].Rows[i][4].ToString("m/d/yyyy");

Comment: Should I guess what error? Or can you give me a hint?

Comment: I got the result only date, when i was loading from dataset to string......      follow the code below                         string strStartDate = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[i][4].ToString().Substring(0,10);

Comment: @Nirmala that's unreliable; the output of `DateTime.ToString()` depends on the system's regional settings.

Comment: to apply the formatted ToString() overload you need to first cast that value to a `DatetTime`. So, try this instead: `strStartDate = ((DateTime)dataset.Tables[0].Rows[i][4]).ToString("M/d/yyyy")`

Comment: also, in the format string, the `M` is a capital one. If you use lowercase (`m`) you may get minutes instead of months.

Answer (score 0):

try it, it will work
select  CONVERT(date,column_name) from table_name