# need help to group my result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by

I am using sql server 2008 r2. here's my query.

```
    SELECT  TOP 25 A.*, U.Displayname AS UserName,
            SU.Displayname AS SmoothieAuthorName, 
            S.Name AS SmoothieName, S.Id AS SmoothieId
    FROM    dbo.Activity AS A 
            LEFT JOIN dbo.[User] AS U ON A.UserId = U.Id
            LEFT JOIN dbo.[User] AS SU ON A.SmoothieAuthorId = SU.Id
            LEFT JOIN dbo.Smoothie AS S ON A.SmoothieId = S.Id

    WHERE   A.UserId = 2 --@UserId
            AND A.UserId <> A.SmoothieAuthorId
    ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
```

following is my result.  now, i need to group them by SmoothieId and CreatedDate (only group date part, ignore time).  First two should only return one back, 3 to 5 should only return one back. not sure how to do it, please help.

```
Id  ActionType  UserId  SmoothieId  SmoothieAuthorId    CreatedDate             UserName    SmoothieAuthorName  SmoothieName    SmoothieId
1   view        2       128         1                   2013-01-15 20:05:03.403 mike        test1234            new testing 2d  128
2   view        2       128         1                   2013-01-15 20:16:24.733 mike        test1234            new testing 2d  128
12  view        2       128         1                   2013-01-16 21:45:56.167 mike        test1234            new testing 2d  128
13  view        2       128         1                   2013-01-16 22:12:51.217 mike        test1234            new testing 2d  128
14  view        2       128         1                   2013-01-16 22:12:54.407 mike        test1234            new testing 2d  128
15  view        2       69          1                   2013-01-16 22:19:54.783 mike        test1234            sdfsdfwww       69
```

Comment: Instead of A*, specify only columns which are required and make sure they are same except for columns which you wanted to 'GROUP BY' i.e, Smoothield and CreatedDate. And mention all them in GROUP BY clause and for date, try GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, CreatedDate)

Comment: Here is what I meant, consider first two records, you said only one record needs to be populate. But id is 1 and 2, so GROUP BY treats them as two different records. Think of GROUP BY as a bucket where we put elements which have same attributes.

Comment: When you ask any question please provide full detail for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need ALL columns from A including Id, I think you'll have a have a hard time including Id. I think you'll need to explicitly list the columns from A you are after. 
I've also assumed you want a count of records you are grouping, hence the Count(TheDate) element.

Other than that, look at [getting just the date portion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/113055/685760) of a datetime and group on that.

Something like;

```
SELECT ActionType, UserId, SmoothieId, SmoothieAuthorId,
       TheDate, Count(TheDate) AS Occurances, UserName, SmoothieAuthorName, 
       SmoothieName, SmoothieId
  FROM (
    SELECT  TOP 25 A.ActionType, A.UserId, A.SmoothieId,  
            A.SmoothieAuthorId, 
            DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, CreatedDate)) AS TheDate, 
            U.Displayname AS UserName,
            SU.Displayname AS SmoothieAuthorName, 
            S.Name AS SmoothieName, S.Id AS SmoothieId
    FROM    dbo.Activity AS A 
            LEFT JOIN dbo.[User] AS U ON A.UserId = U.Id
            LEFT JOIN dbo.[User] AS SU ON A.SmoothieAuthorId = SU.Id
            LEFT JOIN dbo.Smoothie AS S ON A.SmoothieId = S.Id
    WHERE   A.UserId = 2 --@UserId
            AND A.UserId <> A.SmoothieAuthorId
    -- ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
) x GROUP BY ActionType, UserId, SmoothieId, SmoothieAuthorId, UserName, 
             TheDate, SmoothieAuthorName, SmoothieName, SmoothieId
    ORDER BY The Date DESC
```

**Note** This isn't tested, it is just a quick suggestion at what I'd try.

Comment: it works, I have to make some small changes, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question.  Assuming you want distinct values for those columns, then just use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CAST(CreatedDate to Date) as DateWanted, 
    SmoothieId  
FROM 
(    
    SELECT  TOP 25 A.*, U.Displayname AS UserName,
            SU.Displayname AS SmoothieAuthorName, 
            S.Name AS SmoothieName, S.Id AS SmoothieId
    FROM    dbo.Activity AS A 
            LEFT JOIN dbo.[User] AS U ON A.UserId = U.Id
            LEFT JOIN dbo.[User] AS SU ON A.SmoothieAuthorId = SU.Id
            LEFT JOIN dbo.Smoothie AS S ON A.SmoothieId = S.Id
    WHERE   A.UserId = 2 --@UserId
            AND A.UserId <> A.SmoothieAuthorId
) t
```

Reviewing your comment, you say you need all fields in the Activity table.  What do you expect to receive in your Id column for the first 2 records, 1 or 2?  Are all the other values in the other columns the same?  To just get a single record, you're going to need to either pick one row over the other, or do a group by with the columns that have the same information.

Good luck.