# check if date time is of today after 8 am server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have the following table

```
ID      UpdatedDate
---     ------------
1   2013-03-04 08:05:07.203
2   2013-03-04 07:05:07.203
3   2013-03-05 10:05:07.203
```

Now I want to show records only which occur after 8.oo AM today only.

for that I am doing as following

```
select * from tab
where 
LastUpdatedDate > GETDATE()
and datepart(hh, LastUpdatedDate) >= 8
```

the issue occurs if I run this query after the time mentioned in the updatedDate.
in that case `LastUpdatedDate > GETDATE()` fails and returns nothing.

Any idea on how to go about this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the date part only from a SQL Server datetime datatype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)

Comment: Yes I m using Sql server and I don't need just date part.. i also need to check on time part.

Comment: Is LastUpdatedDate actually UpdatedDate in your table or am I missing something?  Is that a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from tab
where 
    convert(varchar(11),LastUpdatedDate,101) > convert(varchar(11),getdate(),101)
and 
    convert(varchar(11),LastUpdatedDate,108) >= '08:00:000'
```

**101 - extract date part

108 - extract time part** ( 24 hour clock format)

Answer (score 3):

I know you've already accepted an answer, but doing this using string comparisons is a really bad idea - it precludes any possibility of using an index.

Instead, why not round the return value from `GETDATE()` to 08:00 today, and directly compare the `LastUpdatedDate` column to that:

```
select * from tab
where 
    LastUpdatedDate >=
       DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'20010101',GETDATE()),'2001-01-01T08:00:00')
```

The `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` pair are used to do the rounding I've described. They work because of the fixed relationship between the two dates I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

`dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)` will give you the date of today with time part `00:00:00`. Useut that the third parameter in `dateadd(hour, 8, ...` and you have a `datetime` value where the time is `08:00:00` that you can use to compare against your column.

Applying functions to columns should if possible always be avoided because that will make your query [Non-Sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

```
select *
from tab
where UpdatedDate >= dateadd(hour, 8, dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0))
```