# SQL query to change datetime to time

Tags: sql

I need to obtain only the time part of a datetime variable without the making it a text file so no varchar

is there a way to get only 9:11:02  from "1/2/2013  9:11:02" without varchar conversion?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  SQL Server?  MySQL?  Oracle?  What version?

Comment: What do you mean by text file?

Comment: this depend upon your database as well
[How to return the date part only from a SQL Server datetime datatype][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype

Comment: Do your homework :

Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
SELECT
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108) AS Time,
```

OR

```
SELECT
CONVERT(TIME,GETDATE()) AS TIME
```

Comment: `without varchar conversion`

Answer (score 1):

try this format for mysql

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(tstamp,'%r') AS stamp from table name
```

E.G.

```
mysql> select * from test;
+---------------------+
| stamp               |
+---------------------+
| 2013-10-10 09:10:11 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(stamp,'%r') AS stamp from test;
+-------------+
| stamp       |
+-------------+
| 09:10:11 AM |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MSSQL, it's still conversion to varchar, but it's data presentation...

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select CAST('1/2/2013 9:11:02' as TIME)
```

This will give you the time with a trailing ".00..."