# Date format in sql server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have date in format `2013-08-05 12:45:56`. But I want to store this in format `2013-08-05 00:00:00` in database.

The thing I want is, I don't want to save the time in database.

I am using:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VoucherDate", VoucherDate.Date);
```

But still it is saving the time. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using:

```
VoucherDate.Date.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: This is not an optimal solution and the reason for this is because dates should be stored as dates (which is actually a 3 byte number). This answer casts the date into a string which is just wrong for all purposes but presentation. Please see the answer from @christiandev instead.

Comment: @Mikael Östberg You are right, i just showed a fast solution, the `ToShortDateString` should be used for presentation pourpouse as you stated

Answer (score 2):

If you're using **SQL 2008** or above, then you can use the `Date` data type

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675168.aspx

If you want to get the **Date** part only in **C#**, then you can use the `Date` property e.g.

```
var fullDate = DateTime.Now;
var dateOnly = fullDate.Date;
```

But, if you're only looking to store the date portion, then consider changing the **SQL datatype**.

Answer (score 1):

Use the date column type instead of datetime

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx

Comment: is there no any other way that I pragmatically save ONLY the date?

Answer (score 0):

Even you have Date, or DateTime column in database, when you read data back to your program you can format the display date by giving correct DataTime format string.

like `dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd)` , then you will not get any time as output

Answer (score 0):

Once I too had a similar problem, with the help of this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/113055/1671639) I fixed it.

Your `C#` code:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("VoucherDate", VoucherDate.Date);
```

Tune your `SQL` query like below mentioned,

```
DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @VoucherDate))
```