# Query from a timestamp based on a date?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, netbeans, jql

How do I execute a query based on date?
As you can see below, I have a table with the attribute PURCHASEDATE as a timestamp.
[image]
My current query is

```
 String query = "SELECT t FROM TransactionE t WHERE t.purchaseDate = '" + currentDate + "'";
```

currentDate in this case is "2013-10-22"

My query above would never return a result because of the timestamp.
How do I query from a timestamp based on a date?

Thanks guys! =)

Comment: Can you use a `PreparedStatement` ? Would be easier to set the `Date` directly than using a `String` to represent the `Date`

Answer (score 0):

[How to return the date part only from a SQL Server datetime datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype/113051#113051)

Use the answer given here.

Comment: If that's the case, the question is a duplicate.