# SSRS: Creating a difference between the beginning of the day to the execution time

Tags: sql, datetime, reporting-services, reporting

I am having a bit of an issue with my SSRS report I am trying to run.  I am trying to have a report pull from the beginning of the day (to be ran daily) and the execution time.

I have:

```
(Rest of the SQL here)WHERE fa.ReceivedDate between @prmStartDate and %executionTime
```

In @prmStartDate currently I have =DateValue(today) which is creating an error when running.

Comment: Is the database sql server?

Comment: Yes, sorry that I did not mention that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this not work?

```
where ReceivedDate >= cast(getdate() as date)
and ReceivedDate < getdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

If it will always use the current date, then you could use the GETDATE function in SQL server and you just need a way to strip off the time portion on the first date.  [A method I like is suggested here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)

Your code would look like this:

```
(Rest of the SQL here)WHERE fa.ReceivedDate between DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())) and GETDATE()
```

If you want to allow the user to choose a different day's data, just add a parameter instead of the GETDATE function:

```
(Rest of the SQL here)WHERE fa.ReceivedDate between @DateParam and DATEADD(dd, 1, @DateParam)
```