# Working Query Optimization (SQL Server 2005)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, query-optimization

I have a table `Orders`, and I am getting order date specification like expiry date etc, from a client/user, but I don't need order expiry time. Below query is with datetime like:

```
SELECT 
    orderDate as Order_DateTime,  
    convert(varchar(10),orderDate,120) as Order_Date,
    DATEADD(dd,2,orderDate) as Order_Expiry_DateTime,
FROM 
    [Orders]
WHERE 
    orderId = 55;
```

The result is:

```
Order_DateTime          |  Order_Date   | Order_Expiry_DateTime   
2013-12-19 21:54:00.000 | 2013-12-19    | 2013-12-21 21:54:00.000 
2013-12-19 19:21:00.000 | 2013-12-19    | 2013-12-21 19:21:00.000 
2013-12-19 19:29:00.000 | 2013-12-19    | 2013-12-21 19:29:00.000 
2013-12-24 22:10:00.000 | 2013-12-24    | 2013-12-26 22:10:00.000 
2013-12-25 18:00:00.000 | 2013-12-25    | 2013-12-27 18:00:00.000 
2013-12-24 23:11:00.000 | 2013-12-24    | 2013-12-26 23:11:00.000 
2013-12-24 20:37:00.000 | 2013-12-24    | 2013-12-26 20:37:00.000
```

Now in following query, I remove time part from `Order_Expiry_DateTime`.

The result is up to my requirement but can I optimize this query to some extent?

```
SELECT 
    orderDate as Order_DateTime,  
    convert(varchar(10), orderDate, 120) as Order_Date,  
    convert(varchar(10), (DATEADD(dd, 2, orderDate)), 120) as Order_Expiry_Date   
FROM 
    [Orders]   
WHERE 
    orderId = 55;
```

The result is good as needed like:

```
Order_DateTime          |  Order_Date   | Order_Expiry_Date
2013-12-19 21:54:00.000 | 2013-12-19    |   2013-12-21 
2013-12-24 22:10:00.000 | 2013-12-24    |   2013-12-26 
2013-12-25 18:00:00.000 | 2013-12-25    |   2013-12-27 
2013-12-24 23:11:00.000 | 2013-12-24    |   2013-12-26 
2013-12-24 20:37:00.000 | 2013-12-24    |   2013-12-26
```

Can

```
convert(varchar(10), (DATEADD(dd, 2, orderDate)), 120)
```

be replaced with something better? I searched but was unable to find one, so please guide me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype

Comment: But I doubt that performing an extra operation on that Order_Expiry_DateTime field can be called "optimization"

Comment: In SQL Server **2008** and newer, you could easily use `CAST(orderDate AS DATE)` to get the date-only portion - but for **2005** I don't think there's much you can do about this expression ...

Comment: @Sohail I think this way is good enough, however performance will be impact more on other things like where clause or how you join etc

Comment: Your computation is invoked on about 10 rows. It would be hard to even measure any difference, no matter what you do. This is <1% the cost of query execution.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure OrderId is indexed and then make sure insterts and updates are not effected on that table if you do add one.