# How to get DATE from DATETIME Column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I have 3 columns in Table TransactionMaster in sql server

1) transaction_amount

2) Card_No

3) transaction_date-- `datetime` datatype

So, I want to fetch SUM of  `transaction_amount where Card_No=' 123'` and `transaction_date= todays date`.<----- excluding time IN SQL

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype?rq=1

Answer (score 130):

Simply cast your timestamp `AS DATE`, like this:

```
SELECT CAST(tstamp AS DATE)
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb/24)

In other words, your statement would look like this:

```
SELECT SUM(transaction_amount)
FROM mytable
WHERE Card_No='123'
  AND CAST(transaction_date AS DATE) = target_date
```

What is nice about `CAST` is that it works exactly the same on most SQL engines (SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL), and is much easier to remember how to use it.
Methods using `CONVERT()` or `TO_DATE()` are specific to each SQL engine and make your code non-portable.

Comment: This doesn't work in SQL Server 2005 or earlier as the *date* data type was added in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Extended support for SQL Server 2005 [ended on April 12, 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/sql-server-2005). If you are still running SQL Server 2005, you will no longer receive security updates. Upgrade to SQL Server 2014, SQL Server 2016, or Azure SQL Database.

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
select * 
from transaction 
where (Card_No='123') and (transaction_date = convert(varchar(10),getdate(),101))
```

Comment: So here you should consider that the RHS side of equal to will return date in DD/MM/YYYY format. You can refer to more format options in this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(SQL.105).aspx

Comment: CAST() didn't work for me using SSRS but convert did. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use the following

```
select sum(transaction_amount) from TransactionMaste
where Card_No = '123' and transaction_date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111)
```

or the following

```
select sum(transaction_amount) from TransactionMaste
where Card_No = '123' and transaction_date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120)
```

Comment: missing from tablename

Answer (score 2):

Use `Getdate()`

```
 select sum(transaction_amount) from TransactionMaster
 where Card_No=' 123' and transaction_date =convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 102)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(transaction_amount) FROM TransactionMaster WHERE Card_No ='123' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111)
```

The `GETDATE()` function returns the current **date and time** from the SQL Server.