# DATE type not working in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, date, types, sql-server-2008-r2

I've been reading all over the place that DATE type should work starting with SQL Server 2008, for example: [stackoverflow.com/a/126984/1155650](https://stackoverflow.com/a/126984/1155650)

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and for some reason the DATE type is not recognized. Am I missing something?

When I execute this:

`SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())`

I get this error message:

> Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Type DATE is not a defined system type.

Comment: Are you running in a compatibility mode other than 2008 R2 (i.e. compatibility mode 100)?

Comment: can you query this and tell us if you see date listed: select * from sys.types
WHERE name LIKE '%date%'

Comment: @Angel_Boy I ran the query and it only returns two types: smalldatetime and datetime

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables When I run a "select name, compatibility_level from sys.databases" I get all the names of my databases and all of them show a compatibility level of 90. Would this be the problem you think? I'm not familiar with compatibility levels and stuff.

Comment: @sergeidave - yes, that means that while you are using SQL Server 2008 R2, the database is running as if it were a SQL 2005 database.  Whoever is in charge of the database may have had a good reason for this, or it may have been by accident.  Before changing it, you should read up on it:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Got it! Can you post this as an answer? I will go ahead and select it as the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`Type DATE is not a defined system type.`

Looks clear, your system do no accept DATE type, perhaps you are running on SQL Server 2005 or earlier, or compatibility mode..