# select date part only in sql server

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, sql-server-2005

Im trying to get the date part of the date column to compare two dates, but could not get date part directly, i tried this `Convert(date, getdate())` but this does not work with sql server 2005 as we are using that, and when i tried `DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))` it gives `2008-09-22 00:00:00.000` where i want only date part without time i-e 00,
taken both from the posts:
[How to return the date part only from a SQL Server datetime datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)

What ihv done is `convert(VARCHAR(10),'2014-04-21 00:00:00.000')` and it returns `2014-04-21` but it is now in `varchar`.

Is there some way so that i may get the date part only in date type in sql server 2005.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is very simple, try using Cast instead of convert, check my ans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some way so that i may get the date part only in date type in
>   sql server 2005.

No, the `date` datatype was added in SQL Server 2008. The best you can do is to use a datetime with the time part `00:00:00`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, It is for SQL 2008

```
select Cast(getdate() as Date) as onlyDate
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual trick to remove the time from datetime is to cast to float and take the int part and cast it back to datetime:

```
declare @d datetime;
set @d = getdate();
select cast(floor(cast(@d as float)) as datetime);
```