# How to convert any time in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm to yyyy-mm-dd hh 00:00:00.000

Tags: sql, sql-server

When using getdate() I'm getting, for example, `2014-04-23 15:51:31.763`.

I want to have `2014-04-23 00:00:00.000`

How can I achieve that?

Comment: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-trim-time-from-datetime & http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/trim-time

Answer (score 0):

A Similar Question has been posted and answered:

[How to return the date part only from a SQL Server datetime datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)

However, to achieve your exact desire:

select convert(datetime, CONVERT(date,getdate()))

Answer (score -2):

change it to simpledate format as yyyy-mm-dd and then convert it back to yyyy-mm-dd-xx:xx:xx:xxx then the timestamp will be removed and resetted to zero