# SQL: Query where date is like today

Tags: sql-server

I have a little problem with my SQL Query:

I have this value on my table: `2014-10-23 00:00:00`

I have a record like this each 2 minutes every day, and I need to `SELECT` all the value of today.

Now I made this:

```
WHERE mytable.data LIKE CURDATE()
```

and it doesn't work. I tried a lot of things found here on stackoverflow and nothing could help me.
Thanks for answer.

Comment: Did you tried `GETDATE()` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype

Comment: @Fka I tried GETDATE and it doesn't work too.

Comment: @KHeaney I already tried that, cause i tried a lot of things and I could not found a solution, now I'm gonna try the Tony's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say which version of SQL Server you are using, if you have the `DATE` data type available you can cast the datetime returned by `getdate()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to strip off the time part.

But then you need a range to find all the matching rows, something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE mytable.data >= CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
  AND mytable.data < CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE()) AS date)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7802d/2)

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks you about your corrections at my question and I'm sorry to didn't say my SQL version, it's 5.1.73.

Comment: I used this form:
AND mytable.data >= CAST( NOW( ) AS DATE ) 
It seems enough about what i need, and it works as well.
Thanks you about your support.