# Compare dates in MS SQL using Convert

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, datetime

I want to do the correct way to get a date from a ***@parameter*** that contains the complete datetime, that user gets from a calendar from **TFS File**.

In the `select` I would want to use something like `CONVERT(varchar(10), @FechaHasta.Value, 120) AS DATE01` and then get the only date, throwing out the time from the parameter.

---

For the next step, I would want to compare it with another date in `WHERE` clause, having this code :

[image: Awful code]

Then, I would want to make this work on for looking for between two dates, and the last one, **throwing out the time from the datetime**.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the date part only from a SQL Server datetime datatype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming `@FetchHasta` is a `datetime`

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @FetchHasta, 101)
```

is what gets you just the date part. i.e. `10/28/2014 1:10 PM` would simply become `10/28/2014`.

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(v=sql.80).aspx)

EDIT: Alternatively, [How to return the date part only from a SQL Server datetime datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)

Comment: yes, but then, I put the '... AS date01' and compare in the where clause like that name?

Comment: No. You can put the `AS date01` for the column name if you wanted, but you would have to redo the calculation in the `WHERE` clause. It may be better to add a new variable before your `SELECT` query with the above calculation so you can use that in both places instead of calculating it repeatedly.