# SQL select where startdate is today's date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime

I am trying to write a query where the clause is when the start date for an employee is todays date.

```
select * from tbl_employees
where Startdate = getdate()
```

The issue is that Startdate is '2014-12-09 00:00:00.000'
and the function `getdate` is coming back with the date and time like '2014-12-09 08:25:16.013'

How can I write a query that only consider's the date?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using? MySQL? 2008?

Comment: I am using mircosoft sql 2008

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the date part only from a SQL Server datetime datatype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)

Answer (score 10):

You want just the date portion.  The easy way is:

```
select *
from tbl_employees
where cast(Startdate as date) = cast(getdate() as date);
```

However, if you want to use an index, it is best not to have the column in a function call.  So, this is better:

```
where (StartDate >= cast(getdate() as date) and StartDate < cast(getdate() + 1 as date))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from tbl_employees 
where CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Startdate,110) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use to compare only DATE section not time..some thing like

```
IF CAST(DateField1 AS DATE) = CAST(DateField2 AS DATE)
```

OR

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 112)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT (date, SYSDATETIME())
    ,CONVERT (date, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())
    ,CONVERT (date, SYSUTCDATETIME())
    ,CONVERT (date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    ,CONVERT (date, GETDATE())
    ,CONVERT (date, GETUTCDATE());

/* Returned 
SYSDATETIME()      2007-05-03
SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()2007-05-03
SYSUTCDATETIME()   2007-05-04
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  2007-05-03
GETDATE()          2007-05-03
GETUTCDATE()       2007-05-04
*/
```

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188751.aspx

So using any of these will give you just the date