# Generate DATE value alone in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-date-functions

I have a query with a column `received` and the value `2014-02-13 19:34:00`. I fetch the date alone using `DATE(received)` and value is `2014-02-13`

In MySQL I use the following query:

```
SELECT DATE(received) AS Mydate, status  
FROM Notification
WHERE project = 'proj001'  
GROUP BY Mydate 
ORDER BY received;
```

How to generate same value in SQL Server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the date part only from a SQL Server datetime datatype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)

Comment: On an unrelated matter (may be out of your control) `WHERE project='proj001'` is not a very good way of doing things for a number of reasons. Combining a string and a number almost always results in having to split them later. Leading zeros are a real pain and can be displayed even if they are not stored.  If all rows have `proj` then it is redundant & not needed, if they can have different values, create a separate type column. You can then make the digit portion an int.  Indexing your string will take up more disk space and cache memory than a `ProjectType char(1), ProjectNo int` will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `cast` or `convert` in SQL Server. `Cast` is ANSI standard. `Convert` is SqlServer specific

```
 select cast(received as date),status FROM Notification   -- or convert(date,received)
 WHERE project='proj001'  
 GROUP BY cast(received as date),status 
 ORDER BY cast(received as date);
```

Comment: For using ANSI standard functions: +1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2008 and higher then

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, '2014-02-13 19:34:00')
```

if you are using an older version then

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, '2014-02-13 19:34:00'))
```