# How to get only end of month dates in pyspark sql?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can we select the dates with end of month only using pyspark ?

## Setup

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


import pyspark
spark = pyspark.sql\
          .SparkSession\
          .builder\
          .appName('app')\
          .getOrCreate()

# sql
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext, SQLContext

sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': np.random.randint(0,100000,365*3),
    'date': pd.date_range('2010-01-01',periods=365*3)
})


df.head()
sdf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df)
sdf.printSchema()
sdf.show(5)

# create table
sdf.createOrReplaceTempView("MyTable")
spark.sql("select * from MyTable limit 2").show()
```

## My Attempt

```py
q = """
SELECT id,date
FROM MyTable
WHERE DAY(DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) = 1
ORDER BY id

"""

spark.sql(q).show()
```

The query q works in usual SQL, but does not work in pyspark.
How to make it work?

## Related Links

- [SQL Query to find the last day of the month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646585/sql-query-to-find-the-last-day-of-the-month/19714940)
- [Get the last day of the month in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051488/get-the-last-day-of-the-month-in-sql)
- [Return just the last day of each month with SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866054/return-just-the-last-day-of-each-month-with-sql)
- [SQL SELECT First Day and Last Day of the Month.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28433449/sql-select-first-day-and-last-day-of-the-month)

Comment: try `select .... where date = last_day(date)`

Comment: @jxc Thanks this solves the problem.