# Changing datetime to date data type with date format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sap-iq

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(varchar, dateissued, 105) AS date) FROM table1;
```

The above SQL statement returns null values instead of expected values.
I cannot spot the error.

Comment: Which DBMS do you use? MySQL or SQL-Server? Due to the fact that you use `CONVERT` I guess you use SAL-Server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the date part only from a SQL Server datetime datatype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)

Comment: Don't you know if you're working with SQL Server or Sybase IQ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(50),CONVERT(date,dateissued ,105)) as newDate
```

Answer (score 0):

These SQL will useful to you.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2010-06-25 09:16:04','%m/%d/%Y') AS DATE
```

Thank you