# Use of SUBSTRING function in WHERE clause using SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, database

I am using SQL Server 2008 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2008. I have a database table which contains a column for data and time as string. In that column I have both date and time. In my application I have to select date and based on that dateI. I have to get the data from table and show data grid view control.

So I want to compare only with date.

And I referred the below link. But it is not working for me.

[Use of SUBSTRING function in where clause](http://www.dailyfreecode.com/code/substring-function-292.aspx)

I tried this query, but it's not working for me.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tAerator 
WHERE SUBSTRING(fldAEdnt, 0, 10) = '07-07-2015'
```

Can you please give me way to solve this problem?

Thanks & regards

Comment: related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype -- besides, why would you store a timestamp as a varchar?

Comment: what happens? do you get an error?

Comment: Fine answers, but really the problem is not here. Why on earth do you allow dates to be stored  as strings?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM tAerator WHERE Convert(date,fldAEdnt)='2015-07-07'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tAerator WHERE SUBSTRING(fldAEdnt,1,10)='07-07-2015'
```

Changed 0 to 1, because in sql server string beginning index is 1

Comment: You should add what exactly you changed because at first glance it looks quite same.

Comment: @SujiD No problem. But we actually should not store date + time as a string in database. I guess you are facing some old databases.

Comment: @SujiD if it helps, pls accept~