# Declare a date variable from month and year SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to make a new variable of type `Date` by passing the `Month` and `Year`

I don't know the syntax, but maybe something like:

```
DECLARE @Date Date
SET @Month(Date) = @Month 
SET @Year(Date) = @Year
```

The `Month` and `Year` are some parameters of my application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the date part only from a SQL Server datetime datatype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean [DATEFROMPARTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/hh213228(v=sql.110).aspx) ?

```
DECLARE @Date Date = DATEFROMPARTS ( @Year, @Month, @Day )
```

EDIT: This function only available after SQL Server 2012. 
For SQL Server 2008. You may use the following

```
SET @Date = CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @year) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @month) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @day) AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do a number of things to accomplish this task...
an easy way is to just declare the variables, then in the select statement where clause you can add them.  so:

```
declare @year as int (or whatever data type you need to use)
as
select * from yourtable 
where year = @year and month = @month
```