# How do you return only the date of a datetime field, and make it sortable?

Tags: c#, date, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

I looked at this question, but it wasn't really the same:

[How to return the date part only from a SQL Server datetime datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)

What I need to do is return just the date piece, but also make it so that it sorts properly.

I currently have this:

```
convert(varchar(10),a.Work_Start,101) as [Work Start]
```

I'm using this in a sortable gridview in C#.  The problem is, when I sort it in ascending order, 01/07/2016 comes before 12/30/2015 because 01 comes before 12.  So, I think converting to varchar isn't what I want.

Comment: Just return the entire DateTime and apply the format string you want in the gridview column

Comment: If you _just_ need date part of your `Work_Start` column, why don't define it as [`date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) type instead of `datetime` at start?

Answer (score 1):

What if you cast the the DATETIME to DATE.

For example:

```
SELECT CAST(Work_Start AS DATE) AS [Work Start]
```

Comment: This worked in terms of sorting, but it includes a time (00:00:00 AM).  Any idea how to get rid of that?

Comment: There's no Date type in C#, so you'll get that value once you are in the GridView.  So you'll need to format in the GridView column as @Alberto said.