# Show DateTime value in combobox without time part (just "1/06/2016")

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm creating a scheduler and I'm getting the value of the dates from a database. When I display the dates in a combo box it adds " 12:00:00 a.m" to all the values at the end of the dates for example "1/06/2016 12:00:00 a.m." instead of just "1/06/2016" the 12 am is not shown with the values when displayed in the database or in a data grid and i tried to replace slots.replace but that didn't work

```
 DataTable day = new DataTable();
 foreach (DataRow db in timeslots.Tables["schedules"].Rows)
 {
    string slot = db["sdates"].ToString();
    if (!comboBox2.Items.Contains(slot))
    {
        comboBox2.Items.Add(db["sdate"].ToString());
    }
 }
```

Comment: A `DateTime` always has a date and a time.  Include a format in your `ToString()` to format the result however you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DataTable day = new DataTable();
foreach (DataRow db in timeslots.Tables["schedules"].Rows)
{
    string slot = ((DateTime)db["sdates"]).ToShortDateString();
    if (!comboBox2.Items.Contains(slot))
    {
        comboBox2.Items.Add(slot);
    }
}
```

As others said, dates from db are converted as DateTime, and DateTime already contains a function to get as an string just the date part, ToShortDateString();

Comment: Exactly!! `ToShortDateString()` is easiest and simple solution

Comment: @ToKeen I would recommend you this method.

Comment: @TalhaIrfan: Indeed, and it will already take care for the date format depending on the locale. I don't know why people like to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Ridiculously, I discovered this method merely two weeks ago (_that too by a student of me_). I felt really stupid when I knew about it. Totally agree!!

Answer (score 1):

Since C# doesn't have a `Date` datatype. All the db date values are converted into `DateTime`. You can always format your output to get only the date part.

In WPF/Data binding you can directly use the StringFormat property:

```
StringFormat={}{0:dd-MM-yyyy}
```

while in coding you can use String.Format like:

```
String.Format({0:MM-dd-yyyy}, x.Date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `db["sdate"]` is a DateTime object you can Specify the Format along with the `.ToString()` as like the following, which will give you the result in the expected format:

```
string DateOnlyString= db["sdate"].ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
if (!comboBox2.Items.Contains(DateOnlyString))
{
   comboBox2.Items.Add(DateOnlyString);
}
```

Take a look into more formatting options [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx), Alternatively you can collect only Date From the database using proper [`CAST` or `CONVERT`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype) functions, So that additional formatting can be avoided and you can use the result directly

Comment: when i use that i get the error 'No overlord method for 'Tostring' takes 1 argument

Comment: @ToKeen: which means that the `db["sdate"]` is already a string; So to make it work you need to convert it as DateTime then to String, Instead of this repeated works, You can use query to get the result

Answer (score 1):

By default the DateTime struct on C# displays 12:00:00 AM if you don't set any time value. If you want just date part, use `varname.Date` (assume varname is your DateTime variable).

Or use String.Format to ensure it has correct format:

```
var date = String.Format({0:MM/dd/yyyy}, varname.Date);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option here is to simply try to convert it to `DateTime` and make sure it's valid. Then you can call the `ToShortDateString` method on it.

```
        DataTable day = new DataTable();

        foreach (DataRow db in timeslots.Tables["schedules"].Rows)
        {
            string slot = db["sdates"].ToString();
            DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;
            var isValidDateTime = DateTime.TryParse(slot, out dt);


            if (!comboBox2.Items.Contains(slot))
            {
                if(isValidDateTime && dt != DateTime.MinValue)
                {
                    comboBox2.Items.Add(dt.ToShortDateString());
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: If db["sdates"] comes from db it's already a DateTime, so why you're converting it to string and then again to datetime? also, as you're using dt as an output parameter it doesn't needs to be initialized.

Comment: @Gusman He had it converted to a string, not me I just added what he had and showed him how to do it. I changed the example though, but you are wrong that dt doesn't need to be initialized.

Comment: no, I'm not wrong, you can test it, any variable used as out parameter in a function doesn't needs to be initialized as the function must intialize obligately the out parameter.

Comment: Maybe you should test it. Also you have to take into account that the slot can be null.

Comment: 1-if slot is datetime it cannot be null, 2-again, no, there's no need to initialize it, I'm bored of doing it, you can check it, the compiler sees you're using the var as output parameter and doesn't complains about it not being initialized.

Comment: Yes I can be null from the Database, if you initialize a DateTime in C# then it can't be, it would always be DateTime.MinValue.

Comment: So you're stating what I said, if it's a datetime it cannot be null.

Comment: But if it comes the the database it can be null if nulls are allowed and if it's not converted to DateTime object.

Comment: .net retrieves the data types from the table definition, not row by row, so if the field type is datetime it will be always datetime, and thus, a datetime cannot be null, what you stated first was right, if it's null then it will be DateTime.MinValue, so there's no need to check it. Also, your code is using db["sdates"] directly which will throw an exception as it will be a DateTime, not an string, so you must add a ToString at the end, what will also throw an exception if the value was null.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding StartTimes}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat='dd.MMMM-yyyy'}" />
              </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ComboBox>
```