# ASP Classic SQL query to get cumulative ammounts per day

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic, jet

I am struggling with a SQL query I have a collection process and I want to have a query that show me every day how much we have collected so far during the current month in a cumulative way. I have all the information in one table named Procesado the date field is Process Date and the amount is in lcamnt Field.

So far I have this:

Query:

```
SELECT 
    Procesado.ProcessDate, SUM(Procesado.lcamnt) AS Monto 
FROM 
    Procesado 
WHERE 
    Procesado.ProcessDate >= Procesado.ProcessDate 
GROUP BY 
    Procesado.ProcessDate
```

Table value

Table Name: `Procesado`

```
ProcessDate  lcamnt  
05/26/2016   $1000  
05/26/2016   $500  
05/27/2016   $2000  
05/27/2016   $1000  
05/28/2016   $5000
```

Desired output

```
05/26/2016   $1500  
05/27/2016   $4500  
05/28/2016   $9500
```

Comment: If ProcessDate is a datetime field, you should just use convert in your group by to remove all the times.

Comment: I would try remove the "Where Procesado.ProcessDate>=Procesado.ProcessDate", I would think that you would get nothing from that.

Comment: the problem is that i am using amcharts to charting the output but so far the actual query just show me the collected per day i need to see per day the cumulative result so far in order to take decisions in case we are not meeting the collection target

Comment: ...though on second thought, the linked question is for when you have a unique ID column. So in this case you'd have to first do a plain GROUP  BY query, and then get a cumulative sum of that, at which point you might as well just do the running total in VBScript.

Comment: See the following SO article for details: http://stackoverflow.com/q/113045/964043  But you should be able to do GROUP BY CONVERT(date, Procesado.ProcessDate) as long as you are SQL 2008 or newer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select p.ProcessDate,
       (select sum(lcamnt)
        from procesado p2
        where 
              p2.ProcessDate <= p.ProcessDate
       ) as Monto
from  procesado p
group by p.processDate
```

Comment: if this answer helped you please mark it as the correct answer.. thanks

Comment: Why didn't you just edit the other answer?, we have now lost all that useful information from the comments because you've deleted it!

Comment: It won't let me for some reason