# Need in and out to come in same line and remove null values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, null

I am having a table called alfa

```
intime                      |   outime                     |    ID  |   Accountid   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
2016-06-23 06:53:00.000     |   NULL                        |   1   |   1234        |            
NULL                        |   2016-06-23 17:04:00.000     |   2   |   1234        |
```

I am expecting the output like

```
intime                      |   outime                     |    Accountid   |   
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------       
2016-06-23 06:53:00.000     |   2016-06-23 17:04:00.000     |   1234        |
```

I am trying to run this query:

```
    select * from alfa
    where intime is not null

and  exists
(select * from alfa as a
where a.accountid=alfa.accountid
and out is not null)
```

But it not giving me the output as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing full data the query might be way wrong, but assuming you will always have only 2 records for the same `AccountId` (one record where `intime` is `null` and one record where `outime` is `null`), you can use join on the same table to get the data you need;

```
SELECT a.intime, b.outime, a.AccountId
FROM alfa a 
    LEFT JOIN alfa b ON a.AccountId = b.AccountId 
        AND CONVERT(date, a.intime) = CONVERT(date, b.outime)
        AND b.intime is null
WHERE a.outime is null
```

Here I used alias `a` and filtered only records that have `outime` value `null`. Then I joined it to alias `b` (where records only have `intime` value of `null`) based on `AccountId`.

The query assumes that you will always have records where `outime` is `null`, but not necessarily where `intime` is `null`, therefore `LEFT JOIN` was used.

**UPDATE:** Based on comment I added another condition to `JOIN` - joining date only from `intime` to date only from `outime`. The method for extracting the date only is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/113055/3697011).

Comment: for every accountid there will be 2 entry, for 1st  entry intime will be the actual intime and outtime will be null, and for 2nd entry intime will be null and outtime will be the actual outtime. And it will be on daily basis

Comment: this is what i expected your updated answer is correct. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this is what you need.

```
SELECT MIN(t.intime),MAX(isnull(t.outime,0)),accountid
FROM alfa t
group by t.accountid
```