# How to get only date from date time using Asp. Net c#?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datetime

In sql database, value is in this format `2016-07-16` and it's datatype is `date`.

But when i am getting it gives me like that : `7/16/16 12:00:00 AM`

I want to get only the date `2016-07-16` but with this format `16/07/2016`.

How to get it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return the date part only from a SQL Server datetime datatype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you fetch the data from the sql you should manipulate the data and change this value. i don't know if your using linq or using EF.

if you use linq

```
var query = from p in db.table
            select new view{
               CreatedOn = p.CreatedOn.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
            };
```

but if you use EF and code first you can set the GET method on its property like this :

```
private DateTime _createdOn;

public string CreatedOn {

    get {
         return _createdOn.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }
    set{
        _createdOn = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Mate for your precious time.

Comment: @ManishTiwari Your property `CreatedOn` is not right.

Comment: Won't it give a compilation error? the return type is datetime but you are returning a string @M.R.Safari.

Comment: Actually i am not using this whole code i grab that idea from it and implement it in my code and here it what i did it `var date=item.DUE_DATE; string dueDate = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");`

Answer (score 0):

public string GetDateOnly(string DateString)
{

```
    DateTime _retVal = Convert.ToDateTime(DateString);
    return _retVal.ToString('dd/MM/yyyy');
```

}

this this method where by passing datetime string

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This is what I did following @M.R.Safari using the Entity Framework migrations and code first approach.

```
    [Required]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public string StartDateShort
    {
        get
        {
            return StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        }
        set
        {
            StartDateShort = value;
        }
    }
    [Required]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string EndDateShort
    {
        get
        {
            return EndDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        }
        set
        {
            EndDateShort = value;
        }
    }
```

I did get an error on the Set method using @M.R.Safari example since it was trying to overwrite the StartDate(DateTime) value to a String, so I instead used the Set method for the String version. I edit only the StartDate(DateTime) value in my forms and the string  value gets updated automatically. I use the string value for views.