# Convert Decode from Oracle to Case from MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, decode

I have this line I am struggling with to convert a query from Oracle to SQL Server 2012. the following line is:

```
DECODE(SUM(DECODE(a.canceldate, NULL, 1,0)), 1, NULL, To_Date(MAX(TO_CHAR(a.canceldate,'yyyymmdd')), 'yyyymmdd')) dCancelDate,
```

As I inteprete is to convert it like:

```
case a.canceldate 
   (when sum(case a.canceldate when Null then 1 else 0 end)) 
   when 1 
       then 0  
       else convert(datetime,a.canceldate) 
end max(a.canceldate) as dCancelDate,
```

I will appreciate some assistant, my line is not correct for SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `decode` formula is equivalent to

```
case sum(case when a.canceldate is null then 1 else 0 end) when 1 then null
     else to_date( ... )    end dCancelDate, ...
```

One mistake I saw in your translation is that you have `when sum(...) when 1`. You can't have it both ways, it is either `when sum(...) = 1` or `sum(...) when 1`. It may be the only mistake, I didn't look too hard.

What you have within the `to_date()` is horrible; are you converting dates to character strings, then take the max IN ALPHABETICAL ORDER and then translate back to date? Why? Perhaps just so you delete the time-of-day component? That is a lot easier done with `trunc(max(a.canceldate))`.

Comment: @JoelJacobson - the two possible syntaxes for `case`, one with a logical condition (like an `=` but it can be other things too, like `is null`) and the other just with values to compare to, are called "**simple** `case` expression" and "**searched** `case` expression", at least in Oracle. Not sure if SQL Server supports both; I used both in my translation. If it doesn't work as-is, try to use only the "simple" syntax.

Comment: So I gave it a shot, but `trunc(max(a.canceldate))` doesn't recognize the function, I try not sure the originator code person from oracle, but I just need to convert it as it is thank you.

Comment: @JoelJacobson - Did the `case` expression translation work? If you can't test due to the `max(...)` (date computation), replace that part with a simple date (like SYSDATE in Oracle, not sure what SQL Server has) just to see if the translation of `decode` is correct. If you need further help on the date computation, perhaps that's a separate question you can post here (not related to translating DECODE to CASE).

Comment: the date magic in the second part of the expression can be solved without string conversion, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/113055/21336

Comment: Thank you it worked for me, I replace the trunk for :
`case sum(case when a.canceldate is null then 1 else 0 end) when 1 then null
     else max(a.canceldate) end,`

Comment: @JoelJacobson - I hope you didn't spell `trunk` like that? In SQL Server, like in Oracle, the spelling is **`trunc`**, and the function should work similarly (see the documentation for any differences).