# SQL Server 2008 R2 - convert() works but cast() does not - any suggestions?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

And please, before marking this as duplicate I have read this post many, many times [the first thing that always pops up in google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype) but I do not think it addresses my question.

In pass-through queries via ODBC to SQL Server 2008 R2...

This DOES works:

```
 (SELECT x, convert(date, y) FROM so_q1);
```

but this DOES NOT work:

```
 (SELECT x, (cast y as date) FROM so_q1);
```

Any idea why?

Comment: `(cast y as date)`?  Do you mean `cast(y as date)`  -  if thats not it please share the error details,.

Comment: @AlexK.- /snort - thank you - it does not work because it is the incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 3):

```
(SELECT x, (cast y as date) FROM so_q1);-- does not work because it is the incorrect syntax.

(SELECT x, cast( y as date) FROM so_q1); --works just fine.
```

thank you @AlexK