# how to find ( SYSDATETIME()-1) < login_time in below query?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to calculate the currently logged in users for which i tried the below query:

```
select COUNT(*)from [dbname] 
where  login_time < SYSDATETIME()   
and logout_time is NULL
```

But i want to get the records for only current date so i tried :

```
select COUNT(*)from [dbname] 
where  ( SYSDATETIME()-1) < login_time < SYSDATETIME() 
and logout_time is NULL
```

This seems to be incorrect. So how to form the query properly? I cant use GETDATE() or Datetime.now() as it will give the secs as well which wont match with the datetime in the database

Comment: As for the later part of the query.. I have a mechanism to clear the logout time and set it as NULL  when the user logs out and save it in a a lastlogin column.

Comment: Why not search for `logout_time` is NULL? If this field is not reliable then you might want to rethink your approach. If this is a web based application then getting logout time can be tricky.

Comment: what do you expect sysdatetime -1 to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from [dbname] 
WHERE login_time < SYSDATETIME()  
AND CONVERT(date, login_time) = CONVERT(date, getdate())
AND logout_time is NULL
```

You want to use `CONVERT(date, getdate())` as of SQL Server 2008

[`CONVERT(date, getdate())` Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/113055/8572813)

Comment: I don't think that `login_time < SYSDATETIME() ` is necessary?

Comment: @PeterSmith its her way of checking if someone is logged in.. login_time lower then currenttime = logged in | and login_time = current date = today. This covers all of his needs

Comment: I think it's 'her' :-). Also, how can the login time be in the future?

Comment: Thats ryt..because I sometimes have records where the login time is for an older date and the logout time is null, so even those records are being counted.

Comment: @PeterSmith my apologies, and login_time can't be in the future. But not checking it equals that everything that has the same date as today is logged in.

Comment: @Tomm Beg to differ. The last two conditions say logged in today and not logged out. The SYSDATETIME() adds nothing to that.