# Filter sql results based on Timestamp

Tags: sql

I have the following CODE

`$thedate = "2018-06-04";  // YYYY-MM-DD`

```
SELECT * 
FROM (`leadactivity`) 
WHERE statusdate = $thedate 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 25
```

I am trying to only show the results where statusdate is = to the date provided. However because in sql the column autoupdates with Timestamp, it's including the time, and for some reason is just not giving any results.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Which database? You need to convert your datatime to a date or match using wildcards (which may be a lot slower on larger databases). Datetime functions are slightly different for each engine - if this SQL Server it's a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-only-the-date-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks like MySQL.  One simple way is:

```
SELECT la.*
FROM leadactivity la
WHERE DATE(la.statusdate) = $thedate 
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 25;
```

However, the use of the `DATE()` function prevents the use of an index.  So, a better approach is:

```
SELECT la.*
FROM leadactivity la
WHERE la.statusdate >= $thedate AND la.statusdate < $thedate + interval 1 day
ORDER BY la.id DESC
LIMIT 25;
```

Comment: Best solution for mysql query crack through php

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
          SELECT * FROM (`leadactivity`) 
          WHERE  statusdate like  '%"$thedate"%' 
          ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25
```

Answer (score 1):

When comparing timestamps with date values, a time-of-day of midnight (ie `00:00:00`) is assumed. Specify a *range* of timestamps based on the date from `00:00:00` to `23:59:59`, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (`leadactivity`)
WHERE statusdate between '$thedate 00:00:00' and '$thedate 23:59:59'
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25
```

Depending on your language and database, the syntax to achieve this will vary.

Although converting the timestamp to a date before comparing is simpler, your database won’t use the index on the timestamp column (if one exists), resulting in the worst performance.