# How to convert DATETIME result into DATE on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date

Here is the logic which isn't working as it returns a DATETIME result. Any help would be much appreciated. I've tried to change the data type to DATETIME2 but not working.

here is the code :

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATE = '0001-01-01' 
SELECT DATEADD(QQ, DATEDIFF(QQ, 0, @CurrentDate), 0) AS FirstDayOfQuarter, 
       DATEADD(QQ, DATEDIFF(QQ, -1, @CurrentDate), -1) AS LastDayOfQuarter, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, DATEADD(DAY, (6- 
       DATEPART(DAY, @CurrentDate)), @CurrentDate)),0),120) AS FirstMondayOftheMonth
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return only the Date from a SQL Server DateTime datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-only-the-date-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)

Answer (score 1):

Date data type can handle **1582-10-15 to 9999-12-31** and here you are trying '0001-01-01'.

Details [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014)

Comment: thank you for your reply. I've just read the link you sent and found out that 1582-10-15 to 9999-12-31 is actually for Informatica.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the version, but `SELECT CONVERT(date, getdate())` is probably the best approach (assuming you're on 2008 or later, which, at this point, you should be).

Obviously replace getdate() with whatever you need it to convert.

Comment: @A Hettinger Thank you for your reply. I'm using SQL Server 2017 and the problem arises when I use the DATEDIFF and DATEADD functions as it returns DATETIME result.

Comment: You should be able to wrap each of the DATEDIFF and DATEADD calls with the CONVERT.