# How to separate date & time from a date time in SQL?

Tags: sql

2019-09-05 23:07:16.643
I want to get 2019-09-05 & 23:07:16.643 separately.

Comment: Please provide what you have tried so far. Also, if this is just about SQL, why is the question tagged C#? Will C# solutions be okay with you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return only the Date from a SQL Server DateTime datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-only-the-date-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)

Comment: sry for the mistake. This is my first question in this platform, I want to solve this in SQL.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please [add a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1):

You can see this link [Convert datetime in sql](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/) and use the conversation format of your preference.

something like this in sql

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 111) as OnlyDate, convert(varchar, getdate(), 8) as OnlyTime
```

for c#

```
var date = DateTime.Now.Date; //get only date
var time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay; //get only time
```

Answer (score 0):

As by the assumption that database is not known can try to manipulate datetime by splitting it before and after space.

```
   Select SUBSTR(datetime,1, 
      Instr(datetime, ' ')) as date,
    Substr(datetime, Instr(datetime, ' ')+1, 
      length(datetime)) as time from table
```