# Pandas - Remove Timestamp

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

**I am trying to calculate basic statistics using pandas. I have precip values for a whole year from 1956. I created a "Date" column that has date for the entire year using pd.date_range. Then I calculated the max value for the year and the date of maximum value. The date of maximum value show "Timestamp('1956-06-19 00:00:00" as the output. How do I extract just the date. I do not need the timestamp or the 00:00:00 time**

```
#Create Date Column
year = 1956
start_date = datetime.date(year,1,1)
end_date = datetime.date(year,12,31)
precip_file["Date"] = pd.date_range(start=start_date,end=end_date,freq="D")

#Yearly maximum value and date of maximum value
yearly_max = precip_file["Precip (mm)"].max(skipna=True)
max_index = precip_file["Precip (mm)"].idxmax()
yearly_max_date = precip_file.iat[max_index,2
```

[Image of output dictionary I am trying to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSG5P.png)

Answer (score 0):

May be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-only-the-date-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype) question, although I can't tell whether you are trying to convert one DateTime or a column of DateTimes.

Comment: Thanks I just needed the .date argument so added the following line to extract date only.
yearly_max_date = yearly_max_date.date()