# GetDate() not using dates correctly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the below SQL query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, st_duedate, 103) as 'Due Date',
    CASE 
        WHEN st_duedate < GETDATE() THEN 'Overdue'
        WHEN st_duedate = GETDATE() THEN 'Due Today'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day,st_duedate,getdate()) <= 7 THEN 'Due within 7 Days'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day,st_duedate,getdate()) > 7 THEN 'Due after 7 Days'
    END AS 'Due when'
FROM st_1
```

However, `st_duedate` dates that are dated today are coming up as 'Overdue' and anything after today comes up as 'Due within 7 days' even if the date is months away.

Is it something to do with the converting of the date? I've just tried having `st_duedate` as the column name instead of converting but still have the same issue.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: The problem is that you're using `CONVERT(varchar, st_duedate, 103)` to get formatted string instead of proper date/datetime.

Comment: The data type of `st_duedate` is datetime

Comment: @MaciejLos if I remove the conversion I am still getting the same issue

Comment: If I remove the format the time is all 00:00:00.000 which I presume will affect the "due today" issue but then the dates months away still has "due within 7 days"?

Comment: It appears that you only need the "date" part of the `datetime` value. Perhaps this will help: [How to return only the Date from a SQL Server DateTime datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-only-the-date-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)

Comment: `DATEDIFF(day,st_duedate,getdate())` is always going to return a *negative* result if `st_duedate` is in the future. I think you've got that logic the wrong way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest moving the `DATEDIFF` calculation into a subquery so that you're just working with one integer value to consider cases for<sup>1,2</sup>:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, st_duedate, 103) as 'Due Date',
    CASE 
        WHEN daysDiff > 0 THEN 'Overdue'
        WHEN daysDiff = 0 THEN 'Due Today'
        WHEN daysDiff >= -7 THEN 'Due within 7 Days'
        ELSE 'Due after 7 Days'
    END AS 'Due when'
FROM (select st_duedate, DATEDIFF(day,st_duedate,getdate()) as DaysDiff from st_1) x
```

You'll notice I've also simplified the last expression in the `CASE` since we seem to have exhausted the possibilities

---

<sup>1</sup>Your existing code switched from direct comparisons to using `DATEDIFF` part way through and ended up "reversing the sign" of the logic which is why the last two cases weren't working as expected.

<sup>2</sup>Also using just `DATEDIFF` logic with `day` automatically ignores any time components of the `datetime` values, which was the other main problem here.