# How to remove fractional seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2019 Express. How can I get a date and time column to NOT show fractional seconds? The only choices in the drop-down are `datetime`, `datetime2` and `datetime2(7)`. If I edit the 7 to a 0, it still shows fractional seconds.

I'll handle this another way since no one seems to have an answer to my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return only the Date from a SQL Server DateTime datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-only-the-date-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype), this this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/126984/724039

Comment: This sounds like the problem is how you choose to *display* the value, not the data type itself.

Comment: Shouldn't you solve this problem in the front-end by choosing an appropriate format?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the convert in your queries?
If yes, using atetime2(0) will do the trick

```
select CONVERT(DATETIME2(0), DateCreated)  from apps
select CONVERT(DATETIME2(0), GETDATE())  from apps
```