# How do I use SQL CONVERT to convert this pattern to date only?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's my SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE MY_DATE_COLUMN >= CONVERT(DATETIME2, '2022-04-04 15:22:20', 1)
```

I get this message:

> The input character string does not follow style 100, either change the input character string or use a different style.

I've also seen this message at times but haven't determined what causes the different messages:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I've also tried at least 10 other style values and none of them work.  What is wrong with my SQL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return only the Date from a SQL Server DateTime datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-only-the-date-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)

Comment: The datetime string format `2022-04-04 15:22:20` is actually style `121` and not `1`. Change to style `121`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you let `TRY_CONVERT()` handle the formatting, it will work:

```sql
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetime, '2022-04-04 15:22:20');  -- 2022-04-04 15:22:20.000
```

### Demo

If you want a date only, then use:

```sql
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(date, '2022-04-04 15:22:20');  -- 2022-04-04
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to convert the date/time to the date portion only.  This solution leaves the time portion attached.

Comment: Then convert it to a date as a second operation

Comment: Then convert to a date rather than datetime, q.v. the updated answer.