# SQL Query including time calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Had a good search here but can't see anything that gets my mind in gear for this one.

Basically I have a table call Diaries, this contains fields such as StartTime EndTime, I need to do a calculation that works out the difference in minutes between StartTime and EndTime. then for each row that fits that day I need to add up the result in minutes.

Something like:

```
Select DiaryID, TotalMinutes 
from (Select (EndTime - StartTime) / 60 AS SubTotalMins 
      from Diary Where ID = Diary.ID) AS FirstSelect 
     (Sum(FirstSelect.SubTotalMins) As TotalMinutes 
Where ID = Diary.ID
```

The above is rubbish of course, but you can see what I am trying to work out.

For each row, work out the difference between End and Start in minutes.
For all rows that match the where clause sum.
Return the sum.

Any ideas?

Regards

Comment: can you add the table schema please and say what platform this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure it's specified in the SQL Standard, but most SQL implementations have some sort of function for determining intervals.  It's really going to boil down to what flavor of SQL you're using.

If you're working with Oracle/PLSQL:

```
SELECT NumToDSInterval(enddate- startdate, 'MINUTE') FROM MyTable
```

In SQL Server/T-SQL:

```
SELECT DateDiff(n, startdate, enddate) FROM MyTable
```

In MySQL:

```
SELECT SubTime(enddate, startdate) FROM MyTable;
```

I'm sure there's one for SQLite and PostGre and any other flavor as well.

Comment: Thanks DateDiff was enough :-) the perfect function for what I needed the rest is easy.

Thanks

Comment: If T-SQL is the flavor you're working with, make sure you look at gbn's solution as well. The method he uses group by date is by far the most efficient of it's kind.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly (for SQL Server at least)...

```
SELECT
    SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, StartTime, EndTime)),
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, StartTime), 0) AS [Date]
FROM
    Diary
WHERE
    DiaryID = @ID
GROUP BY
    DiaryID /* in case for all DiaryIDs */,
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, StartTime), 0)
```

Note: this removes the time component from a "datetime" value. Works by calculating the number of days since zero (= 01 Jan 1900). [It's the most efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133081)

```
DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, StartTime), 0)
```

[DATEDIFF in MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

Comment: Given the OP's seeming lack of familiarity with DateDiff, I'd suggest adding an explanation of what DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, StartTime), 0) does.

Comment: Its a function I had not come across before, but works wonderfully now. Thanks. 

just need to work out how to accept the answer.

Comment: I had actually seen the dateadd+datediff thing a few times while searching for the most efficient date calculations.  I'm trying to convince my DBA to add this and a few similar ones (first of month, end of month, etc.) as functions in the master database.

Comment: I have to say that they are massively worth while, over the last 12 hours I have created 50 views that have these functions implemented which means a drop of about 20% in network traffic for some of our live reports, normally the traffic is not an issue, but its always good to reduce.